# Reversing page order from a point onward

Tags: page-numbering

In my document, I want pages from a specific point onward to appear in reverse page order, i.e. the last page should come first, then the penultimate page, etc. How can I do it?

(I don't want to reverse content - only the order in which pages appear)

Comment: You are talking about the full page content, not just changing the numbering of the pages (as the used {page-numbering} tag would suggest)? Changing the order of the pages is not possible in TeX itself. You would need to post-process the output PDF (or PS) file. However, this will most likely remove or break all hyperlinks.

Comment: I want to re-order the pages themselves in the PDF. If it is not possible I can accomplish this quite easily with pdftk, but I hopes for something more elegant...

Comment: I doubt it is possible within [pdf](La)TeX (I wish I am wrong), but you can use [pdftk](http://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-the-pdf-toolkit/) and using it you can obtain desired effect. Go with [cat](http://www.pdflabs.com/docs/pdftk-man-page/#dest-op-cat) operation. EDIT: Ah, too late and more importantly needlessly. :)

Comment: @GadiA: No, AFAIK reordering pages is not supported by TeX. For this it would need to buffer a lot of pages before writing them out.

Comment: @przemoc, @GadiA: Does `pdftk` support/retains the hyperlinks? There is e.g. also the `pdfjam` script (based on the `pdfpages` LaTeX package) which will remove all hyperlinks.

Comment: @Martin: Actually I've never checked it till now. I reversed PDF and links in TOC and bib references still work.

Comment: @MartinScharrer: Reversing the page tree is trivial in PDF; see my answer on how pdfTeX.

Comment: @MartinSchröder: Ok, I wasn't thinking about reversing the page order using PDF features. That way it would be much easier.

Comment: @GadiA: Just thought I'd mention I've used the solution to your question to complete (well, sort of) a document class for Technion Theses which properly sets the Hebrew content at the end so that you don't have to flip any pages after printing, just bring the thing to the binder. See: [my own thesis](http://www.box.com/s/402kzfx8buyzjyrfq1f4), just submitted.

Comment: Glad to see I had a long term effect... (I used pdftk at the end).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This reverses the order of the pages which are output while `\RPtrue` is set, and keeps pages in the normal order when `\RPfalse` is active. References and hyperlinks should work. I use Heiko Oberdiek's `atbegshi` package to hook into the `\shipout` primitive (which is responsible for sending pages to the dvi/pdf file): instead of sending the pages out, we store them in `\RPbox`. Namely, the contents of `\RPbox` have the form

- Skip of `1 pt`
- First page to be reversed.
- Kern of size `<`*`first page number`*`> sp`
- Second page to be reversed.
- Kern of size `<`*`second page number`*`> sp`
- Etc.

Then in `\RPfalse` we use `\lastkern` and `\lastbox` to retrieve the contents of box registers and ship pages out one by one, with the correct page number in place (this makes sure that references are right). The assignments to `\c@page` are done locally so that the old value is restored once all pages have been output.

Also, I put a `\clearpage` in the macros `\RPtrue` and `\RPfalse` because I thought that would make more sense, but things shoud work without.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{atbegshi}
\newif\ifRP
\newbox\RPbox
\setbox\RPbox\vbox{\vskip1pt}
\makeatletter
\AtBeginShipout{%
  \ifRP
    \AtBeginShipoutDiscard%
    \global\setbox\RPbox\vbox{\unvbox\RPbox
      \box\AtBeginShipoutBox\kern\c@page sp}%
  \fi
}%
\renewcommand{\RPtrue}{%
  \clearpage
  \ifRP\RPfalse\fi
  \global\let\ifRP\iftrue
}%
\renewcommand{\RPfalse}{%
  \clearpage
  \global\let\ifRP\iffalse
  \setbox\RPbox\vbox{\unvbox\RPbox
    \def\protect{\noexpand\protect\noexpand}%
    \@whilesw\ifdim0pt=\lastskip\fi
      {\c@page\lastkern\unkern\shipout\lastbox}%
  }%
}%
\makeatother

% Test document.
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}

  \tableofcontents

  \section{Lipsum 1--50}
  \lipsum[1-50]

  \RPtrue

    \section{Lipsum 51--100}
    \lipsum[51-100]

  \RPfalse

  \section{Lipsum 101--150}
  \lipsum[101-150]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Very cool. This reverses all the pages in the document. How would this work to reverse some subset of the pages from a particular point in the document (as in the OP's question)?

Comment: @Alan Munn: \o/ I also got hyperlinks to work.

Comment: @BrunoLeFloch: This hack stopped working with recent versions of TeXLive; can you [have a look](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/598581/5640)?

Answer (score 2):

The probably never to be released [trunk of pdftex](http://foundry.supelec.fr/gf/project/pdftex/scmsvn/?action=browse&path=%2Ftrunk%2F) (i.e. 1.50) adds the commands `\pdfpagedivert` and `\pdfpageundivert` which work like diversions in [m4](http://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/m4/manual/m4-1.4.16/html_node/Diversions.html#Diversions). With it you can change the order of pages in the resulting pdf any way you like.

It would be a nice feature for LuaTeX and could probably easily be added, if someone requested it.