# Usage of \lastbox

Tags: expl3

As part of our LaTeX3 work, we provide a consistent interface to TeX programming through the expl3 package. We've recently been discussing the TeX primitive `\lastbox`, which is used to inspect or unpack whatever just came before in the typesetting.

From a scan over various packages that use `\lastbox`, its use appears to be restricted (entirely, it seems) to constructions like

```
\setbox\foo=\lastbox
... % do something with box \foo
```

That is, there's no need to provide access to the read-only `\lastbox` variable itself, only a method by which the last box can be assigned to a TeX box for further processing; something like

```
\box_set_to_last:N \foo
... % do something with box \foo
    % no such thing as \lastbox or equivalent
```

We'd propose to only provide the expl3 programmer with this method and promote that any `\lastbox` related functionality use `\box_set_to_last:N` instead. Does this seem sensible? Contrariwise, do you know of an actual use for `\lastbox` that doesn't involve a `\setbox` first?

Comment: I'm rather inclined to say that no other use makes much sense. If you say `\lastbox` (not in outer vertical mode or in math mode where it's disallowed), all you get is nothing, if the last item is not a box; otherwise you get exactly that box, so nothing different from what you'd get without `\lastbox`.

Comment: @egreg: I'd be inclined to follow you on that, but `plain.tex` uses `\lastbox` in `\m@ketabbox` without `\setbox`. (I don't understand what DEK is doing in those macros.)

Comment: @Bruno: I've always wanted to study those macros; but they are rather frightening. :)

Comment: @egreg: they are, but they are also the only case of usage of `\lastbox` without `\setbox` in my texlive install (modulo some copies of the same macros elsewhere, and some clearly erroneous `\box\lastbox` at various places).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Investigating about the use of `\lastbox` it seems that it is always used as

```
\setbox\someboxregister=\lastbox
```

with one *important* exception: line 619 of `plain.tex` contains

```
\ifus@\unvbox\z@\lastbox\fi
```

as part of the magic macros for `\tabalign` (aka `\+`).

I'd say that providing a LaTeX3 interface for the most common use is a good thing to do. One can always rely on the (renamed) primitive, for uses such as Knuth's.

Answer (score 11):

I found three aspects of `\lastbox` not covered by the `\setbox\foo=\lastbox`.

Firstly, I used `\shipout\lastbox` repeatedly after packing all pages of a document in one big `\vbox{<firstpage><secondpage>...}`, to [reverse pages from now onwards](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/25142/2707)

Secondly, `\lastbox` used in vertical mode will take the last box from the current list, and put it back, [inserting the `\baselineskip` or `\lineskip`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/39086/2707) as relevant given the `\prevdepth` that was active above that box. This is perhaps what `\lastbox` is used for within Knuth's `\tabalign` macro. For instance, the following puts several `\baselineskip` glues between the two boxes.

```
\vbox{\hbox{}\hbox{}\lastbox\lastbox\lastbox\showlists}
```

In horizontal mode, something similar happens with the space factor: it is reset to `1000`, as it should following a box. I don't see a use for that, but it is consistent.

```
\vbox{\hbox{}\spacefactor=999\lastbox\showthe\spacefactor}
```

I think we should remain away from those exotic uses of `\lastbox` in LaTeX3, at least until we find real uses. In all cases, `\lastbox` can be replaced by `{\setbox0\lastbox\box0}`.