# Unboxing \hrule's?

Tags: boxes, rules, plain-tex

How do you unbox `\hrule`s such as in this code sample:

```
\setbox0=\vbox{1\hrule2\hfil\break3}
\unvbox0
\setbox0=\lastbox % line 3
\unskip           % \baselineskip
\unpenalty        % \break
\setbox0=\lastbox % line 2
\unskip           % \parskip
% Unbox \hrule?
\end
```

Comment: Only a box can be caught by `\lastbox`. Rules don't. And there's no way to remove them from a list, unless you produce them as a vertical leader (and `\unskip` will remove them). If you look at the macro I suggested, I removed `\noalign{\hrule}` in the first pass just because of that problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

TeX has some primitives for “looking back” and removing a node, storing it into a register: `\lastskip`, `\lastkern`, `\lastpenalty` and `\lastbox`. Other types of nodes can't be examined nor removed.

Note that `\lastskip` only keep information about the size of the last skip, whether it comes from a “real” skip or `\leaders`, so the information about leaders is lost in this case.

All of them do nothing, in the sense that they store a null value, if the last node is of the requested type. As usual, boxes are special: `\lastbox` by itself will remove the last box (if the last node in the list is a box), and reinsert it (see [Usage of \lastbox](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28316/usage-of-lastbox)).

However, a rule node is not a box, so `\lastbox` will do nothing sensible. More explicitly: you can't remove a rule node nor examine it.