# Reverse the page order in an LTR document for an RTL section/chapter

Tags: xetex, languages, polyglossia

I am currently writing a research thesis and the summary chapter is translated into multiple languages, including Urdu (an RTL language). I am using polyglossia and XeLaTeX, and the document compiles without errors. However, I notice that the Urdu translation page order/flow/direction is LTR, the same as the document. Is there some method to reverse the page order for this chapter/section only?

I have created the following MWE which creates a six-page document as an example. The Urdu/RTL section starts on page 3 and ends on page 4

```
\documentclass[15pt]{article}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainlanguage[variant=british]{english}
\setotherlanguage{urdu}

\setmainfont{Amiri}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

    \section{English}
    \lipsum[1-8]

    \newpage

    \begin{urdu}
        \section{اُردو}
        صورتحال کو فروغ دینے کا اعتراف کرنا۔ مسٹر ایکٹنیسی ہم تخمینے سے لطف اندوز ہونے کے ناطے۔ ایک دیر سے منعقد کے طور پر پتہ چلا. ٹھوس قبر کو جانے دیں۔ مڈلٹن کو شک کی عمر اس کی توجہ ہے۔ بنیادی طور پر کئی بستر اس کی خواہش مند ہیں۔ چیمبر پر اتنے لمحوں پر دباؤ پڑا ہے۔ شکوک و شبہات نے ابھی تک انسانیت کو اس کی خواہش کا صحیح جواب دیا۔ منٹر یقین رکھتے ہیں کہ سروس سول سویل میں پہنچ گئی۔ ایکٹونٹی الاؤنس ایک بے تابی میں وسیع شاندار آپ میں پسندیدہ ہے۔

        تعاون یافتہ گھر والوں کی طرف سے فرینکنس کی تعریف کی گئی۔ کے لئے ابھی جمع کردہ پسندیدہ اور بیہودہ نفرت انگیز مشاورت کی۔ لگتا ہے ایک بار پھر سبز لکھا جائے۔ وہ اپنی ہی چیز کو شامل کرتی ہے۔ سختی سے ہم انتہا پسندی کے بطور کمانڈ کمانڈ کرتے ہیں۔ مشتعل ناراضگی سے مالک مکان کا داخلہ اس کے علاوہ مالکن میں ہے۔ بلکہ پوری خواتین تھیں۔ اوہ تجویز کرتے ہیں کہ کھلاڑیوں کا الاؤنس ستمبر میں بے شرم ہے۔ گیٹ انسان کو دن بتائے کہ کون ہے۔

        بیچلر خوشی اس کی تجویز کی ہنسی پر غور کرنا پھینک دینا۔ ہچکچاہٹ واپس آ گئی ایک مکمل طور پر اس کے مردوں کا ہیم ختم ہوگیا۔ باطل طور پر باہمی کاؤنٹی کی تعریف کرنے کے لئے ایک پھینک کے گرمجوشی سے محض رخصتی فراہمی کا نتیجہ ہوں۔ مطلوبہ اعزازی چھوٹی چھوٹی چیزیں خوشی منائیں۔ یقین دہانی ابھی تک بستر فرنیچر آدمی کو بہتر بنا رہا تھا۔ پریشانیوں سے وہ خوشی خوشی خوشی خوشی باتیں سن رہی ہیں۔

        اس سے لطف اندوز ہونے سے متضاد ہے۔ اونچے کمرے میں کرو تاکہ تنخواہ دی جائے۔ کزن پر آپ کو رات کا کھانا کھانا چاہئے۔ سیکس کھڑی دیواروں سے منور سچ شرمائی اور اس کی تین۔ ان کی سالوں سے بچوں کی سچائی۔ معزز عجیب و غریب گھرانوں میں بھی اسی طرح اندر داخل ہوجاتے ہیں۔

        لازمی ہے کہ تم اس کے ساتھ اس کی طرف سے اس سے زیادہ ہو۔ سب سے بڑی بات یہ ہے کہ اس کے نتیجے میں باطل چوک پر تبصرہ کرنا چاہئے۔ ناخوشگوار خاص طور پر اس کی مدد کے لئے کافی تلاش کی۔ ایک شرمیلی ایڈورڈ سیڑھیاں باری ہوئی شاخ میں قانون حیرت والے گھوڑے ہیں۔ ڈیون شائر کے دعوت نامے سے انفرادیت کو فوقیت کا ترجیح مل گیا۔ اعتراض کا تخمینہ مباحثہ کرتے ہوئے وہ پریشان کن رہا۔ اب ہمدردی کی عمر کے ل سادگی کا مقابلہ کرنا۔ اس کا مطلب ہے کہ ان کی جنس سے بچہ موخر ہوسکتا ہے۔ زندگی کو چھوڑنے میں ایک ہار کم ہے۔

        موٹا بیٹا مسکراتے ہوئے مسٹر قدرتی خرچ پریشان دوست۔ لڑکے پیمانے سے لطف اندوز پوچھیں مضامین سیکھنے میں مواد کی حیثیت سے احساسات کو بہتر بنایا گیا ہے۔ غیر مستقل طور پر توہین آمیز سفر بے راہ روی کا سفر کرتے ہیں۔ برینڈن کے بطور پینٹ لذت سمیٹنے کے ل.۔ ہم جنس پرستوں کے افسوس سے زیادہ گرم ہونا چاہئے آسانی سے اب ہونا چاہئے۔ مجھ پر امید بڑھے ہوئے حیرت زدہ خیالات کی بھوک پر بھٹک رہی ہے۔ دلیرانہ دلچسپی رکھنے والے جناب کی دعوت نے خاص طور پر تبدیلی والے لڑکے کو فیصلہ کن دیکھا۔

        اس بات کا یقین کرنے کے لئے زیادہ تر طویل عرصے سے میرا مطلب ہے. ہم کرایے میں طویل مدت کے قابل ہیں۔ غیر معمولی طور پر نہیں یہ خلوص کا اعلان کر رہا ہے۔ پیدائش سیکھیں جو اس نے دیا ہے۔ محفوظ شرم کی لمبائی تمام بیس اشارہ کریں۔ انہوں نے رائے شماری کے جواب میں نو عمر افراد کی رائے دی۔

        دور دراز کے بیچ میں۔ بھوک کا خیرمقدم خیر سگالی لڑکے نے نہیں کیا۔ اس کے تلفظ کے لئے تخمینی تعلیم۔ جان سائز کے اچھے ہم جنس پرستوں کے منصوبے نے پرانی چھت خود بھیج دی۔ انکوائیوٹ نے اس کی دوستی کو ابھی تک کثرت سے سمجھا۔ قدرت اس کا نشان زدہ ہام کا خواہش مند۔

        کزن سسیکس کے تمام مردوں کے سیٹ ہونے سے پہلے گرمجوشی سے سمجھدار فیصلے سے کہیں زیادہ طے پانے پر اس کو سلام کرنا۔ سول لطیفوں میں سے ایک بدتر لنن کی پیش کش چھوڑ دیں۔ تمام جماعتوں نے کپڑے اتارنے سے خوش ہوکر اسے دانستہ قرار دیا۔ اور رہائش گاہ کے لئے تخمینہ لگانے سے نمٹا مطلب اگر وہ مسٹر نہ ہوں۔ کیا زیادہ سے زیادہ مدد حاصل کی ہے. مؤخر الذکر شخص اس میں املاک کی صلاحیت سے محفوظ ہے۔

        دل کی پانی والی عورت نے یہ لکھا۔ مکمل طور پر خاندانوں میں مناسب مکرم محفوظ کرنے سے بہتر ہوا۔ جوش و خروش سے فرنیچر کے بارے میں کچھ ناپائیدار قابل قبول تھا۔ ناشتہ کے تخمینے والے سوالات کو اس کے پسندیدہ انتخاب میں جمع کیا۔ جانا جاتا ہے کہ وہ قابل قدر الفاظ رکھتا ہے۔ اب اس کی تیار ہوشیار آواز کی بات کرو۔
    \end{urdu}

\newpage
\section{English again}
\lipsum[9-16]

\end{document}
```

Essentially, I am looking for a solution that allows the Urdu section to start on page 4 and end on page 3 to make reading the chapter/section easier. I have looked into the KOMA and Polyglossia documentation, but I wasn't able to find anything relevant (I might have missed something though).

Additionally, I am not aware of the proper standards for RTL chapters/sections in LTR documents (or vice versa for that matter) so I am not aware whether this reversing is advisable or even an accepted practice, so any information is welcome.

Edit: Changed class from `scrbook` to `article` as a comment has pointed out that my MWE is not compiling with the latest scrbook class. For reference, I am using koma-script version 3.26b in TeX Live 2019 where the original MWE compiled fine.

Comment: Welcome to the site!  Your example doesn’t compile with recent versions of `scrbook`; better to use `article` for purposes of a minimal example, so that changes in `scrbook` don’t complicate the issue.

Comment: @Thérèse thank you. I have updated the MWE. I have also added an edit note giving the versions I am using. I don't know if I would be willing to update my distribution and packages till I'm done with this project, lest I fix one and break ten things.

Comment: @Thérèse it doesn't compile as section use a sans serif font in with scrbook. One has to add `\setsansfont{Amiri}`.

Comment: I don't think you can automatically change the document direction mid way. If the main document language is English then you are asking for LaTeX to output page 1, 2, 4, 3. As far as I know, you can't do this. If you wanted to do this, the easiest option is probably to make two separate documents and combine them later. So your Urdu section could start from one end of the document and your English content from the other end of the document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reverse-page switch (from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21703/reversing-page-order-from-a-point-onward?rq=1)), which treats pages as boxes and intercepts them at shipout point, generally works well.

`\RPtrue` and `\RPfalse` switch reverse page order on and off.

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
%==================================
%reverse paging
\usepackage{atbegshi}
\newif\ifRP
\newbox\RPbox
\setbox\RPbox\vbox{\vskip1pt}
\makeatletter
\AtBeginShipout{%
  \ifRP
    \AtBeginShipoutDiscard%
    \global\setbox\RPbox\vbox{\unvbox\RPbox
      \box\AtBeginShipoutBox\kern\c@page sp}%
  \fi
}%
\renewcommand{\RPtrue}{%
  \clearpage
  \ifRP\RPfalse\fi
  \global\let\ifRP\iftrue
}%
\renewcommand{\RPfalse}{%
  \clearpage
  \global\let\ifRP\iffalse
  \setbox\RPbox\vbox{\unvbox\RPbox
    \def\protect{\noexpand\protect\noexpand}%
    \@whilesw\ifdim0pt=\lastskip\fi
      {\c@page\lastkern\unkern\shipout\lastbox}%
  }%
}%
\makeatother
%===================================
\begin{document}
\lipsum{5-20}
\RPtrue
This is sample text. Reverse page...A
\newpage
This is sample text. Reverse page...B
\newpage
This is sample text. Reverse page...C
\newpage
This is sample text. Reverse page...D
\newpage
This is sample text. Reverse page...E
\newpage
This is sample text. Reverse page...F
\RPfalse
\lipsum{21-29}

\end{document}
```

Prints pages in this order: 1,2,8,7,6,5,4,3,9

To apply this to multi-page polyglossia output, do not use environments that end up going across page boundaries (`\begin{urdu}`....`\end{urdu}`) - because the `RP` code discards pages (=boxes) from the original stream as it stores them to later output them in reverse, and this technique breaks the environment.

Instead of environments, use switches (`\selectlanguage{urdu}`...`\selectlanguage{english}...`).

MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
%\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainlanguage[variant=british]{english}
\setotherlanguage{urdu}
\newfontface\urdufont[Script=Arabic,Language=Urdu]{Amiri}
\setmainfont{Noto Serif}%Amiri}

\usepackage{lipsum}

%==================================
%reverse paging
\usepackage{atbegshi}
\newif\ifRP
\newbox\RPbox
\setbox\RPbox\vbox{\vskip1pt}
\makeatletter
\AtBeginShipout{%
  \ifRP
    \AtBeginShipoutDiscard%
    \global\setbox\RPbox\vbox{\unvbox\RPbox
      \box\AtBeginShipoutBox\kern\c@page sp}%
  \fi
}%
\renewcommand{\RPtrue}{%
  \clearpage
  \ifRP\RPfalse\fi
  \global\let\ifRP\iftrue
}%
\renewcommand{\RPfalse}{%
  \clearpage
  \global\let\ifRP\iffalse
  \setbox\RPbox\vbox{\unvbox\RPbox
    \def\protect{\noexpand\protect\noexpand}%
    \@whilesw\ifdim0pt=\lastskip\fi
      {\c@page\lastkern\unkern\shipout\lastbox}%
  }%
}%
\makeatother
%===================================

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
    \section{English}
    \lipsum{1-8}

%    \newpage
\RPtrue
%x
%\newpage
%y
%\newpage
%z
%\newpage
    \selectlanguage{urdu}
        \section{اُردو}
        صورتحال کو فروغ دینے کا اعتراف کرنا۔ مسٹر ایکٹنیسی ہم تخمینے سے لطف اندوز ہونے کے ناطے۔ ایک دیر سے منعقد کے طور پر پتہ چلا. ٹھوس قبر کو جانے دیں۔ مڈلٹن کو شک کی عمر اس کی توجہ ہے۔ بنیادی طور پر کئی بستر اس کی خواہش مند ہیں۔ چیمبر پر اتنے لمحوں پر دباؤ پڑا ہے۔ شکوک و شبہات نے ابھی تک انسانیت کو اس کی خواہش کا صحیح جواب دیا۔ منٹر یقین رکھتے ہیں کہ سروس سول سویل میں پہنچ گئی۔ ایکٹونٹی الاؤنس ایک بے تابی میں وسیع شاندار آپ میں پسندیدہ ہے۔

        تعاون یافتہ گھر والوں کی طرف سے فرینکنس کی تعریف کی گئی۔ کے لئے ابھی جمع کردہ پسندیدہ اور بیہودہ نفرت انگیز مشاورت کی۔ لگتا ہے ایک بار پھر سبز لکھا جائے۔ وہ اپنی ہی چیز کو شامل کرتی ہے۔ سختی سے ہم انتہا پسندی کے بطور کمانڈ کمانڈ کرتے ہیں۔ مشتعل ناراضگی سے مالک مکان کا داخلہ اس کے علاوہ مالکن میں ہے۔ بلکہ پوری خواتین تھیں۔ اوہ تجویز کرتے ہیں کہ کھلاڑیوں کا الاؤنس ستمبر میں بے شرم ہے۔ گیٹ انسان کو دن بتائے کہ کون ہے۔

        بیچلر خوشی اس کی تجویز کی ہنسی پر غور کرنا پھینک دینا۔ ہچکچاہٹ واپس آ گئی ایک مکمل طور پر اس کے مردوں کا ہیم ختم ہوگیا۔ باطل طور پر باہمی کاؤنٹی کی تعریف کرنے کے لئے ایک پھینک کے گرمجوشی سے محض رخصتی فراہمی کا نتیجہ ہوں۔ مطلوبہ اعزازی چھوٹی چھوٹی چیزیں خوشی منائیں۔ یقین دہانی ابھی تک بستر فرنیچر آدمی کو بہتر بنا رہا تھا۔ پریشانیوں سے وہ خوشی خوشی خوشی خوشی باتیں سن رہی ہیں۔

        اس سے لطف اندوز ہونے سے متضاد ہے۔ اونچے کمرے میں کرو تاکہ تنخواہ دی جائے۔ کزن پر آپ کو رات کا کھانا کھانا چاہئے۔ سیکس کھڑی دیواروں سے منور سچ شرمائی اور اس کی تین۔ ان کی سالوں سے بچوں کی سچائی۔ معزز عجیب و غریب گھرانوں میں بھی اسی طرح اندر داخل ہوجاتے ہیں۔

        لازمی ہے کہ تم اس کے ساتھ اس کی طرف سے اس سے زیادہ ہو۔ سب سے بڑی بات یہ ہے کہ اس کے نتیجے میں باطل چوک پر تبصرہ کرنا چاہئے۔ ناخوشگوار خاص طور پر اس کی مدد کے لئے کافی تلاش کی۔ ایک شرمیلی ایڈورڈ سیڑھیاں باری ہوئی شاخ میں قانون حیرت والے گھوڑے ہیں۔ ڈیون شائر کے دعوت نامے سے انفرادیت کو فوقیت کا ترجیح مل گیا۔ اعتراض کا تخمینہ مباحثہ کرتے ہوئے وہ پریشان کن رہا۔ اب ہمدردی کی عمر کے ل سادگی کا مقابلہ کرنا۔ اس کا مطلب ہے کہ ان کی جنس سے بچہ موخر ہوسکتا ہے۔ زندگی کو چھوڑنے میں ایک ہار کم ہے۔

        موٹا بیٹا مسکراتے ہوئے مسٹر قدرتی خرچ پریشان دوست۔ لڑکے پیمانے سے لطف اندوز پوچھیں مضامین سیکھنے میں مواد کی حیثیت سے احساسات کو بہتر بنایا گیا ہے۔ غیر مستقل طور پر توہین آمیز سفر بے راہ روی کا سفر کرتے ہیں۔ برینڈن کے بطور پینٹ لذت سمیٹنے کے ل.۔ ہم جنس پرستوں کے افسوس سے زیادہ گرم ہونا چاہئے آسانی سے اب ہونا چاہئے۔ مجھ پر امید بڑھے ہوئے حیرت زدہ خیالات کی بھوک پر بھٹک رہی ہے۔ دلیرانہ دلچسپی رکھنے والے جناب کی دعوت نے خاص طور پر تبدیلی والے لڑکے کو فیصلہ کن دیکھا۔

        اس بات کا یقین کرنے کے لئے زیادہ تر طویل عرصے سے میرا مطلب ہے. ہم کرایے میں طویل مدت کے قابل ہیں۔ غیر معمولی طور پر نہیں یہ خلوص کا اعلان کر رہا ہے۔ پیدائش سیکھیں جو اس نے دیا ہے۔ محفوظ شرم کی لمبائی تمام بیس اشارہ کریں۔ انہوں نے رائے شماری کے جواب میں نو عمر افراد کی رائے دی۔

        دور دراز کے بیچ میں۔ بھوک کا خیرمقدم خیر سگالی لڑکے نے نہیں کیا۔ اس کے تلفظ کے لئے تخمینی تعلیم۔ جان سائز کے اچھے ہم جنس پرستوں کے منصوبے نے پرانی چھت خود بھیج دی۔ انکوائیوٹ نے اس کی دوستی کو ابھی تک کثرت سے سمجھا۔ قدرت اس کا نشان زدہ ہام کا خواہش مند۔

        کزن سسیکس کے تمام مردوں کے سیٹ ہونے سے پہلے گرمجوشی سے سمجھدار فیصلے سے کہیں زیادہ طے پانے پر اس کو سلام کرنا۔ سول لطیفوں میں سے ایک بدتر لنن کی پیش کش چھوڑ دیں۔ تمام جماعتوں نے کپڑے اتارنے سے خوش ہوکر اسے دانستہ قرار دیا۔ اور رہائش گاہ کے لئے تخمینہ لگانے سے نمٹا مطلب اگر وہ مسٹر نہ ہوں۔ کیا زیادہ سے زیادہ مدد حاصل کی ہے. مؤخر الذکر شخص اس میں املاک کی صلاحیت سے محفوظ ہے۔

        دل کی پانی والی عورت نے یہ لکھا۔ مکمل طور پر خاندانوں میں مناسب مکرم محفوظ کرنے سے بہتر ہوا۔ جوش و خروش سے فرنیچر کے بارے میں کچھ ناپائیدار قابل قبول تھا۔ ناشتہ کے تخمینے والے سوالات کو اس کے پسندیدہ انتخاب میں جمع کیا۔ جانا جاتا ہے کہ وہ قابل قدر الفاظ رکھتا ہے۔ اب اس کی تیار ہوشیار آواز کی بات کرو۔
%    \end{urdu}

%\newpage
\RPfalse
\selectlanguage{english}
\section{English again}
\lipsum{9-16}

\end{document}
```

This is a useful technique, and I can use it in a lot of my own texing. Thank you for asking the question. The opportunity to explore is quite valuable.+1

This is also an example where the `.aux` file *must* be deleted after an erroring run.

---

The rest of the original answer merely described symptoms of the page-crossing environment (with various MWEs), so does not add any value here anymore.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Your MWE works when I try it independently, but when I integrate it within my project, the XeLaTex compile process hangs indefinitely. I assume it is because of some incompatibility with either one of my KOMA configurations, or one of the other packages but, unfortunately, I'm short on time to find the incompatibilities to make this work. I am marking it as an answer as the MWE works and that it'll definitely be useful for other people (and hopefully myself in future projects). Thanks very much for putting in the time and effort :)