# Figures on left pages, text on right ones with class book (cont.)

Tags: floats, captions, double-sided

In addition to the very useful discussion [Figures on left pages, text on right ones with class book, numbering only on right pages](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18156/figures-on-left-pages-text-on-right-ones-with-class-book-numbering-only-on-rig), I would like to handle 2 other features:

- the suppression of blank pages automatically inserted by book,
- the possibility to switch between figure and table captions.

Regarding the first, 3 blank pages are added before a new chapter (probably also before a new part) where only 1 should be. I managed to remove one redefining `\chapter` as follows (removing the first line involving `\clearpage`) but not the other.

```
\renewcommand\chapter{
                    \thispagestyle{plain}%
                    \global\@topnum\z@
                    \@afterindentfalse
                    \secdef\@chapter\@schapter}
```

For the second, I defined a new command `\switchcaption` as follows which I call before and after a table respectively with "table" and "figure" as argument.

```
\newcommand\switchcaption[1]{\def\@captype{#1}}
```

By the way, I would be very interested in better understanding

- when it is useful to use directly `\def` instead of `\(re)newcommand` (`\newcommand\@captype{figure}` seems to work just as well as `\def\@captype{figure}`),
- when it is needed to work within `\makeatletter` `\makeatother` (apparently `\newcommand` works differently in both cases: it "reads" the new command name with subsequent braces outside `\makeatletter` `\makeatother` and without braces otherwise),
- why `\addfig` definition needs two statements (one for `\@addfig` and another apparently for its argument).

Thank you very much in advance for your help!

Comment: I'm afraid you're asking two completely different questions here, and that they should be asked separately.
Anyway, as far as I know for question (2a): don't use `\def`, and for (2b): it's needed when you tamper with TeX internal macros which have `@` in their names.

Comment: For your first two btw's see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/655/what-is-the-difference-between-def-and-newcommand and http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8351/what-do-makeatletter-and-makeatother-do.

Comment: Thank you for your fast follow-up! By the way I finally worked out more elegant (and suitable) solutions to the above-mentionned issues. The blank pages were actually linked to the page break inserted by `\include` (I am writing a thesis...). Using `\input` instead solves the problem (without redefining `\chapter`). In addition, I managed to avoid blank pages at the end of the document redefining `\blankpage` to stop recursion (`\renewcommand{\blankpage}{}`). To define table captions, I realised that I could use the command `\captionof` provided by the caption package I am using anyway.

Comment: Regarding your choice of `\include` or `\input`, also see: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/246/when-should-i-use-input-vs-include

Answer (score 5):

After viewing the comments, it seems like the only thing left (even though it is actually not in question form), is to *efficiently* switch between `table` and `caption`. You mention that you currently do this manually:

```
\switchcaption{table}% Switch to table caption
\begin{table}[..]
   ...
\end{table}
\switchcaption{figure}% Switch to figure caption
```

This *manual* interaction could be avoided by adding some code to the beginning and ending of the `table` environment. Such "patching" is possible using the [`etoolbox` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox). It provides `\AtBeginEnvironment{<env>}{<code>}` and `\AtEndEnvironment{<env>}{<code>}` (also `\BeforeBeginEnvironment{<env>}{<code>}` and `\AfterEndEnvironment{<env>}{<code>}`) to insert `<code>` at the beginning/end of environment `<env>`. A little bit more efficient would be to just add:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}% http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox
\makeatletter
\AtBeginEnvironment{table}{\def\@captype{table}}% Switch to table captions at beginning of table environment
\AtBeginEnvironment{figure}{\def\@captype{figure}}% Switch to figure captions at beginning of figure environment
\makeatother
```

to your document preamble that should switch as needed depending on the environment used.

---

**Edit**: The above "solution" may be moot if you are using the `figure` environment for all your `figure`s *and* `table`s. If that is the case, the your `\switchcaption` combination will still be necessary.

To that end, note that you can still use the `table` environment within the command `\addfig`, which necessarily modifies the caption to read `Table x: ...`. This is a common misinterpretation of the `table` and `figure` environments, stemming from their respective names. They are merely wrappers for *any* content, allowing you to place `\includegraphics` commands inside `table` and a `tabular` (say) inside `figure`.

Comment: When the `caption` package is used please don't use `\def\@captype{table}` but `\captionsetup{type=table}` instead. This latter one will not only define `\@captype` but also apply table-local caption options, set an hyperref anchor (if `hyperref` is used), prepare the environment for sub-figures resp. sub-captions etc.