# Figures in odd pages, text in even pages; if no figures, then odd=even pages (i.e., no blank pages w/ numbering and headers...)

Tags: floats, positioning, double-sided

I'm writing my thesis using `\documentclass{book}`. I have plenty of figures and I want them to appear always on the right hand of my manuscript (since this is the "attraction" page when reading, and figures in my field are much more important).

[Figures on left pages, text on right ones with class book, numbering only on right pages](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18156/figures-on-left-pages-text-on-right-ones-with-class-book-numbering-only-on-rig)

[Figures on left pages, text on right ones with class book (cont.)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/32836/figures-on-left-pages-text-on-right-ones-with-class-book-cont)

do not cover this issue quite in the same way, and I didn't manage to improve that into something useful to me...

In this case, the odd pages should have normal headings (differently defined for odd and even pages with `\usepackage{fancyhdr}`), normal numbering and no blank pages should appear unless defined. Figures should try to appear always in the odd pages, BUT if there is more figure pages than text pages, figures should be located in the even pages as normal (see Example 1), and if there is more text pages than figure pages, text should be placed in odd pages as normal (see Example 2). No figures from Chapter 1 should appear in Chapter 2, for obvious reasons.

Example 1

> Output:
>   Text pages: 20
>   Figure pages: 23
>   Three extra odd pages with figures would have appeared and three even pages would be blank.

Instead one should be able to locate some of those figures within the text in the even pages, as normal.

Example 2

> Output:
>   Text pages: 23
>   Figure pages: 20
>   Three extra even pages with text would have appeared and three odd pages would be blank.

Instead one should be able to locate part of text in odd pages, as normal.

I am a newbie, so my apologies if this is posted somewhere and I couldn't find it, or if this problem has an easy solution that I could have solved myself. Now that I've explained in detail, I have the feeling that has no easy solution, though!

I hope you guys can help me!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! It would be helpful if you could provide some more information about (a) the LaTeX documentclass you're using (book? report? memoir? ...) and (b) some of the properties of the figures: do they generally (or all) take up most or all of a page, are some in landscape mode, etc?

Comment: Thanks for the warm welcoming, Mico! As stated I am using documentclass{book}. For the figure part, a bit of everything, but yes, indeed, some of them will be big, so I had to redefine page limits (\topfraction, \textfraction), some take all the page with caption in contiguous pages (\usepackage{fltpage}), some -even several in same page- in landscape mode (\usepackage{pdflscape}). I think the best would be to have some on and off feature, let's say, now figures in odd pages and text in even pages, now editable in normal ways.

Answer (score 14):

I *think* it's enough to define

```
\makeatletter

\def\@floatplacement{\global\@topnum\c@topnumber
   \global\@toproom \topfraction\@colht
   \global\@botnum  \c@bottomnumber
   \global\@botroom \bottomfraction\@colht
   \global\@colnum  \ifodd\c@page\c@totalnumber\else\z@\fi%<<<<<<<
   \@fpmin   \floatpagefraction\@colht}

\makeatother
```

In which the marked line has been  changed to set the number of allowed floats to zero (`\z@`) on even pages and the value of the LaTeX counter totalnumber (`\c@totalnumber`) on even pages.

In the original definition in LaTeX this line is

```
\global\@colnum\c@totalnumber
```

and the totalnumber counter applies to all non-float pages. See Frank's full description of the float parameters here [How to influence the position of float environments like figure and table in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39017/how-to-influence-the-position-of-float-environments-like-figure-and-table-in-lat/39020#39020)

Comment: Great David! Your solution seems to work fine, probably does (but I'm not able to understand how to set the number of allowed floats to zero on odd pages). It's too advanced for me. What is the editable part of it or into what could I change it? By default, figures go to the odd pages (already a big step), except when they are too many, covering then odd and even pages. A little problem is that some big gaps appear in the tex areas; but I didn't have the time yet to dig into that nor I'm able to implement your advise on changing the marked line. Could you explain further, please? I'm sorry

Comment: sorry I wasn't clear, I'll edit the answer

Comment: David, thank you very much for your help! I am soo sorry not to have posted something earlier thanking you for your answer and help; I thought I did this already, and just now realized I didn't. Better later than never... thanks again!