# Ensure figures are placed on an odd page

Tags: floats, positioning, memoir, double-sided

Is there a way to ensure that figures (or other floats) are always displayed on an odd page?

I'm using `memoir` for writing my thesis, which can be set to automatically place e.g. chapter beginnings on odd pages, such that they always appear to the right if a document is printed two-sided.

I currently have some rather large floats of figures, which I would like to, in the same way, always display on odd pages. `memoir` has the built-in command `\movetooddpage`, but this just inserts white space till the next odd page.

So back to my question is there a way to do this, but without inserting the white space and just ensure, that the figures are shown on odd pages? It's less important whether the figures are pushed forward a page or two.

EDIT: I should mention, that I don't want it to apply for my whole thesis, but only for certain sections.

Comment: The answer to [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/43941/) probably solves the problem.

Comment: I saw that question, but it seems to only set the condition globally.
I only want this condition to apply in certain sections and not throughout my whole thesis.
It probably wasn't very clear in my original question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The method used in [Figures in odd pages, text in even pages; if no figures, then odd=even pages (i.e., no blank pages w/ numbering and headers...)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/43941/figures-in-odd-pages-text-in-even-pages-if-no-figures-then-odd-even-pages-i) can be done in a localised sense should be extendible to your case, for example by defining:

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\let\orig@floatplacement\@floatplacement
\newcommand*{\floatsoddonly}{%
  \clearpage
  \def\@floatplacement{%
    \global\@topnum\c@topnumber
    \global\@toproom \topfraction\@colht
    \global\@botnum  \c@bottomnumber
    \global\@botroom \bottomfraction\@colht
    \global\@colnum  \ifodd\c@page\c@totalnumber\else\z@\fi%<<<<<<<
    \@fpmin   \floatpagefraction\@colht}%
}
\newcommand*{\floatsnormal}{%
  \clearpage
  \let\@floatplacement\orig@floatplacement
}
\beg{document}
\floatsoddonly
....
\floatsnormal
```