# Figures on left pages, text on right pages

Tags: floats, positioning, page-breaking, double-sided

I'm writing a thesis in the `book` document class and I'm using a lot of figures to explain the working method. If I use the method proposed in [Figures on left pages, text on right ones with class book, numbering only on right pages](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18156/figures-on-left-pages-text-on-right-ones-with-class-book-numbering-only-on-rig), my professor made the comment that it feels strange to have the text on the left side. He asked if it could be figures on the left and text on the right side. I've tried to do that, but when i do that, my figures go to the next page. This is what I want:

```
l-----------l------------l 
l           l  bla bla,  l
l           l  bla bla   l
l  fig 1    l            l
l           l            l
l           l            l
l-----------l------------l
```

but this is what I get:

```
l-----------l------------l   l-----------l------------l
l           l  bla bla,  l   l           l            l
l           l  bla bla,  l   l           l            l
l           l            l   l  fig1     l            l
l           l            l   l           l            l
l           l            l   l           l            l
l-----------l------------l   l-----------l------------l
```

Is there any possible method to get me the result I want? Or am I making a stupid fault somewhere?

PS: ow, the left page should be left blank if there's no figure.

@Ignasi: Yes that is what I want (if that is possible).

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a "thank you" in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. Upvoting is the preferred way here to say "thank you" to users who helped you.

Comment: the question [figures-on-left-pages-text-on-right-ones-with-class-book-numbering-only-on-rig](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18156/) is related to this; some other considerations are raised in a followup: [figures-on-left-pages-text-on-right-ones-with-class-book-cont](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/32836/)

Answer (score 3):

For that kind of layout I wouldn't use a floating figure. LaTeX's `\cleardoublepage` forces you on to an odd (right hand) page but you want to get on to the even page so

clearpage is

```
\def\cleardoublepage{\clearpage\if@twoside \ifodd\c@page\else
    \hbox{}\newpage\if@twocolumn\hbox{}\newpage\fi\fi\fi}
```

so first define

```
\makeatletter
\def\cleartoevenpage{\clearpage\if@twoside \ifodd\c@page
    \hbox{}\newpage\if@twocolumn\hbox{}\newpage\fi\fi\fi}

\makeatother
```

then you can go

```
\cleartoevenpage
\includegraphics{myfigure}
\clearpage
\captionof{figure}{my caption}
\clearpage
```

and you have full control over the spread. `\captionof` is defined in the `caption` package or its one-line variant  `capt-of` package.

Comment: That doesn't seem to do it. I tried your answer but it still gives me the same problem as described. This is the result I get, using your method: [Click here to see the lay-out.](http://img72.imageshack.us/img72/928/afbeelding1pz.png) The two maps should be displayed next to the first page, because this is where they are mentioned in the text.

Comment: If you are using non-floating figures then they don't move so if you need then first they need to be first in the file. But I'm confused as that image shows captions _below_ the figures but I thought you wanted them on a different page. But maybe I misread you and you do want captions with the figure, but just allow them to float to even pages.

Comment: @Kevin: If I understand your example, your chapter starts in page 3 but you want your figures (declared after `\chapter`) appear on page 2 which is not part of your chapter. So, if figures are declared in page 5 they can appear in page 4 because both are from chapter 1, but not so early.

Comment: Yes Ignasi, if that is possible. There must be a way to put figures on the left page and text on the right one in a book style. There are so much books with that kind of layout.