# How to split a footnote only to odd pages

Tags: footnotes, double-sided, eledmac, eledpar

I have a document which uses the `eledpar` package to edit parallel texts. On the even pages, I have a original text from an author and on the odd pages I have my commentary of the text. All is synchronized by the `eledpar` package.

My problem is concerning footnotes. I have very big footnotes on the original text side (even pages). LaTeX automatically splits these footnote on two (or more) consecutive pages. I would like to split these footnote **only** between *even* pages. I don't want a footnote about the original text to be split on the commentary side (odd pages).

How can I achieve this?

Comment: You may want to read through this question:
http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36486/placing-text-and-footnotes-on-separate-pages?rq=1

Comment: Take a look at this answer of mine (it is for even pages): http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/130249/27635

Comment: @karlkoeller This solution does print footnotes only on even pages **but** doesn't split a big footnote only on even pages (a big footnote started on page 2 will continue on page 3 and not on page 4 which is what I want).

Comment: @Reanimation THe topic you indicated is not answering to my precise question about splitting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The new version of eledmac-eledpar 1.19.0-1.13.0, now send on CTAN, fixes this issue.

Basically, you must:

- set the vertical size allowed to the notes, with `\maxhXnotes[<series>]`
- set that you want notes only for right pages, with `\onlyside[<series>]{<side}`

for example

```
\maxhXnotes{0.8\textwidth}
\onlyXside{R}
```

Read § 4.4 of the new handbook of eledpar for more details.

ps : now, we have an eledmac and an eledpar tag.

Comment: I add this link (to an article in the author website) for the French speakers who want to know more about this update : http://geekographie.maieul.net/164

Answer (score 3):

Actually, there is no way to have any standard split of footnote with eledpar. The split of footnote make page are not synchronous.

I am trying to make a version with not flowing through pages. I could add option for you problem. Please post a message on https://github.com/maieul/ledmac/issues/17.

Please, next time you have a question on eledmac/eledpar, use the ledmac tag. I am looking on the RSS feed on ledmac tag, so I can see your questions.

Comment: I will post a message on the github thread you indicated (in French). Sorry for the ledmac tag (I also added the eledpar tag).

Comment: Thanks. In stackexchange, there is only an historical ledmac tag.

Comment: see the conversation on the github page for the end of this problem

Comment: No, there is a correct tag. For the main problem, I hope to finish this problem in autumn...