# How to print a past value of a counter

Tags: counters, calculations

I have this counter which I have defined using `\newcounter{myCounter}`.

Printing the value of `myCounter` can be easily done via `\arabic{myCounter}`. How can I print the value of (`myCounter` - 2)?

Comment: Related: [Displaying a later value of a counter](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/39356/5764)

Answer (score 3):

Either use the `\label`-`\ref` system if you're stepping `myCounter` via `\refstepcounter` system, or manually calculate it via `\numexpr`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcounter{myCounter}

\begin{document}

\setcounter{myCounter}{5}
\verb|\themyCounter:     | \themyCounter

\verb|\arabic{myCounter}:| \arabic{myCounter}

\bigskip

\refstepcounter{myCounter}\label{myLabel}
\verb|\themyCounter:     | \themyCounter

\addtocounter{myCounter}{2}
\verb|\themyCounter:     | \themyCounter

\bigskip

\verb|\ref{myLabel}:     | \ref{myLabel}

\verb|Calculation:       | \number\numexpr\value{myCounter}-2\relax

\end{document}
```

`\the<counter>` is usually used to represent the value of `<counter>`, and is defined as `\arabic{<counter>}` by default. As reference, see [The `\the` command](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/38674/5764).

More options exist (with LaTeX's [`fp`](http://ctan.org/pkg/fp) and LaTeX3's [`l3fp`](http://ctan.org/pkg/expl3)) if you want to perform more intricate calculations.