# Print a counter after reading the whole document

Tags: counters

I'm working on a document in which I define some numbers. I want to print at the beginning the sum of all these numbers. It's something like the desired result described in this question [Displaying a later value of a counter](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39356/displaying-a-later-value-of-a-counter), but I could not modify that code to obtain what I want.

Here is an example of what I want

```
\documentclass[leqno]{article}
\newcounter{totaldepuntos}
\newcommand\puntos[1]{\textbf{(#1Pt)}\addtocounter{totaldepuntos}{#1}}
\setcounter{totaldepuntos}{0}
\begin{document}
\thetotaldepuntos %Must print 10
\begin{enumerate}
\item \puntos{2} Blablabla %Creates an item, put the text ´(2Pt)´ and     
%sum 2 to the counter totaldepuntos
\item \puntos{4} Blobloblo %Creates an item, put the text ´(4Pt)´ and     
%sum 4 to the counter totaldepuntos
\item \puntos{4} Blublbublu %Creates an item, put the text ´(4Pt)´ and     
%sum 4 to the counter totaldepuntos
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Comment: If the counter starts at `8` and you add `10`, then it has to come to `18`. Why do you want it to print `10` when it is `18`?

Comment: @cfr Lol, sorry. Edited.

Comment: @MrSelberg You have looked at the wrong thread

Comment: Package `totcount`