# doublepage but with almost every leftside blank

Tags: page-breaking, double-sided

### Short Version

Can I create a pdf for doublepage print where the left pages does not interact with the pagecount and having most of them blanks while content on others?

### Long version

I have a printer that can print on both sides of the paper (hurray....?)

While I don't like printing text on both sides I do like the idea of having an image on the leftside with a new chapter starting on the right side.

However, this would force me to print out on double pages. by doing so I would have to place a blank page between each page - except where I want an images (or other content) to be printed.

I have been thinking of generating another pdf with content for only the left sides - blank pages and a few with content. After generating rightside.pdf and leftside.pdf I would be able to shuffel them with

`\includepdf[pages={1}]{rightside.pdf}

\includepdf[pages={1}]{leftside.pdf}

\includepdf[pages={2}]{rightside.pdf}

\includepdf[pages={2}]{leftside.pdf}

\includepdf[pages={3}]{rightside.pdf}

\includepdf[pages={3}]{leftside.pdf}

...`

Besides having to indentify all pages where the chapters begin - **it  just feels stupid**.

Is there a package that deals with strange people like me who want partly singlepage print? I imagine one that interact with \cleardoublepage or something linke that.

Comment: Please let me know if the explanation of the problem was not clear.
+
I am aware that this _could_ be done by printing normal singlepage and then take each paper in front of a chapter and put them in the printer again - printing on the backside of the paper.

Comment: Have a look at [Figures on left pages, text on right ones with class book, numbering only on right pages](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18156/figures-on-left-pages-text-on-right-ones-with-class-book-numbering-only-on-rig/18164#18164)

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution that leaves all verso pages empty unless the current page contains the command `\chapteropening{<material>}` in which case `<material>` will appear on the **previous** verso page. Thus use this command immediately after the `\chapter` command.

```
\documentclass[oneside]{report}

\usepackage{atbegshi}

\AtBeginShipoutFirst{%
   \AtBeginShipout{%
     \AtBeginShipoutOriginalShipout\vbox to\textheight{% 
                     \vss
                     \box\chapteropeningbox
                     \vss
    }}}

\newbox\chapteropeningbox

\newcommand\chapteropening[1]{%
    \setbox\chapteropeningbox\vbox{\hsize\textwidth #1}%
}

\begin{document}

\chapter{A}

1 some text \newpage
2 some text \newpage
3 some text \newpage

\chapter{B}
\chapteropening{ \centering \Huge FOO }

4 some text 

\chapter{C}

5 some text \newpage
6 some text 

\end{document}
```