# Make every other page a float page (or empty)

Tags: floats, positioning, page-breaking, double-sided

I would like to be able to make every other page in a double-sided document be a float page or empty (apart from header w/page number). Ideally this would be the verso page and all floats (unless there are too many, of course) of the facing recto page would be there.

If this works, what is the best way to make the margin of these pages smaller?

(This is for course notes: the empty pages can be used by students for their own notes.)

Comment: This sounds rather like http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/18156/15925

Comment: @AndrewSwann: Indeed, I'll set things in motion to close this.