# Figures on the left (even) page of a book

Tags: graphics, floats, books

There are some more postings on this topic but I've found no working/satisfying solution for my problem.

Some solutions work well for figures spread over the whole document. For me it is much more comfortable to have all pictures in a separate file. Including this once from the include point on I'll have all figures from the file on the left page and all text on the right.

I tried to modify the code from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/38733), but it still is not what I'd like to have. Because if I include the file, I get all figures on the left, but no text on the right - there will be only blank pages.

The major problem is that I've `\documentclass{book}` with about `50` A4 sized images and `70` pages of text. So I want to put all images on the left side and the text on the right for better readability.

*I generate the figure blocks automatically - this is the major reason for having a separate file.*

Comment: Hi, Andreas -- Welcome to the TeX.SX. Your name is shown on the lower right corner automatically, Thus, signature is not required.