# Constrain a float to be positioned on right page only?

Tags: floats, positioning

How can I constrain a float to be positioned only on a new right (recto) page and never on a verso page?

I'd like behaviour similar to

```
\begin{figure}[p]
```

But as if there were a positioning option 'r' like...

```
\begin{figure}[r]
```

Which would only allow the float on a new recto page.

This is different to the request in this question: [Figures on left pages, text on right ones with class book, numbering only on right pages](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18156/figures-on-left-pages-text-on-right-ones-with-class-book-numbering-only-on-rig) or behaviour in the package `semioneside` which give text only on one side and figures only on the other.

As a MWE I'd like my A and B to be on odd pages with text on the even pages.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{graphicx}


\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[p]
  \resizebox{!}{\textwidth}{A}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[p]
  \resizebox{!}{\textwidth}{B}
\end{figure}

\lipsum
\lipsum

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Related: [Force images/tables to verso](http://www.latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=1089#p3837)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

this only allows `p` on odd pages. Note that it doesn't redefine `\clearpage` (including its implicit use in `\end{document}` so any floats pending at the end of the document will be flushed irrespective of page number.

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\def\@floatplacement{\global\@topnum\c@topnumber
    % Textpage bit, global:
   \global\@toproom \topfraction\@colht
   \global\@botnum  \c@bottomnumber
   \global\@botroom \bottomfraction\@colht
   \global\@colnum  \c@totalnumber
    % Floatpage bit, local:
   \@fpmin   \ifodd\c@page\floatpagefraction\@colht\else 2\textheight\fi\relax}
\makeatother

\def\t{%
\begin{figure}[p]
FFFFFF\\FFF\\FF\\F

\caption{ff ff ff}
\end{figure}

TTT TTT TTT TTT
}
\def\z{zz\par zzz\par zzzz\par zzzzz\par}
\begin{document}

\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t

\z\z\z\z\z\z\z\z\z\z\z\z\z\z\z\z\z
\z\z\z\z\z\z\z\z\z\z\z\z\z\z\z\z\z
\z\z\z\z\z\z\z\z\z\z\z\z\z\z\z\z\z
\z\z\z\z\z\z\z\z\z\z\z\z\z\z\z\z\z

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, that works really nicely, although I can't pretend to understand what it's doing!  Making the minimum available height required for a float on an even page twice the possible text height (and so preventing its placement) perhaps?

Comment: @RupertMeese exactly:-)

Comment: @RupertMeese apart from the added if test in setting `@fpmin`, the rest is a copy of the standard definition from the latex format.