# How to add verbatim in a float figure on right page?

Tags: verbatim, afterpage

I've discovered [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/18164/72985) to define the command `addfig{}` to put figures on the right page.

My problem is that it doesn't work if the figure is a `verbatim` element.

Here is a minimal not working example :

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside,12pt]{article}

\usepackage[francais]{babel} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[labelsep=endash]{caption}

\usepackage{afterpage}

% The addfig function definition
\makeatletter
\newcommand\@addfig{\relax}
\newcommand\addfig[1]{\global\long\def\@addfig{#1}}
\newcommand\@putfig{\@addfig\addfig{\relax}}
\newcommand\blankpage{%
\null
\vfill
\@putfig%
\vfill
\thispagestyle{empty}%
\clearpage%
\addtocounter{page}{-1}
\afterpage{\blankpage}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\afterpage{\blankpage}

\addfig{ % The example work without it
\begin{figure}
        \begin{verbatim}
                Something
        \end{verbatim}
        \caption{content of the caption}
\end{figure}
}

First Page

\end{document}
```

Is there a way to redefine the command to accept `verbatim`?

Comment: The command doesn't seem to be doing anything very much (why not simply use `\begin{figure}` ?

Comment: `\afterpage{\blankpage}` at the beginning of the document add blank page after each page. The command `addfig` move the figure on this blank page. It's usefull to set all figures on the backside of the page to print it. `\begin{figure}` alone just add the figure in the text. That's not what I want.

Comment: But it doesn't check that the figure is being added to a a right hand (odd) page it just always throws a blank page. In what way is it usefully different to `\clearpage\begin{figure}` (or variants using `\cleardoublepage` or `\cleartoevenpage` ([eg here](http://www.latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=2868)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `verbatimbox` package can be helpful here.  It allows you to stuff verbatim into a box.  In this case, I stuff it before the invocation of `\addfig` into a box named `\myafterfig`.  Then I can recall that box as part of the figure content.  Because it is a box, I can center it, as well.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside,12pt]{article}

%\usepackage[francais]{babel} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[labelsep=endash]{caption}
\usepackage{verbatimbox}
\usepackage{afterpage}

% The addfig function definition
\makeatletter
\newcommand\@addfig{\relax}
\newcommand\addfig[1]{\global\long\def\@addfig{#1}}
\newcommand\@putfig{\@addfig\addfig{\relax}}
\newcommand\blankpage{%
\null
\vfill
\@putfig%
\vfill
\thispagestyle{empty}%
\clearpage%
\addtocounter{page}{-1}
\afterpage{\blankpage}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\afterpage{\blankpage}

\begin{myverbbox}{\myafterfig}
Something \verbatim $%^&
ANd then &*)$% some more
\end{myverbbox}
\addfig{ % The example work without it
\begin{figure}
\centering
\myafterfig
\caption{content of the caption}
\end{figure}
}

First Page

\end{document}
```

[image]