How to create the guide-words in a dictionary
I want to make a dictionary which is based on an old print version from the 18th century.
The style is to have a two column layout and on top of each page

on the left side the page number plus the guide word from the first entry of this page
on the right side the page number increased by one plus the guide word from the last entry of this page

So the page number increases by 2 for each page.
I found something in the web for the package fancyhdr, but I'm using KOMA script and do not want to change my complete code.
Here is a small working excample:
\documentclass[%
    12pt,
    parskip=false,
]{scrbook}

\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}

\usepackage[german]{babel} % Old rules

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[babel=true]{microtype}
\setmainfont[Numbers={Proportional,OldStyle},Ligatures={Common,Rare,Historic}]{Libertinus Serif}
\setsansfont[Numbers={Proportional,OldStyle}]{GilliusADF}
\fontspec{inconsolata}

\usepackage{ragged2e}

\usepackage{multicol}

\usepackage{lipsum}

% Double page numbering based on: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18156/figures-on-left-pages-text-on-right-ones-with-class-book-numbering-only-on-rig
\renewcommand\thepage{\number\numexpr ((2*\the\value{page})-1)\relax} % Die Seitennummer wird immer um 2 erhöht
\newcommand{\theEvenPage}{\number\numexpr (\thepage+1)\relax} % Die gerade Seitenzahl rechts
 
\lehead{\pagemark}
\rehead{\theEvenPage}
\lefoot{}
 
\lohead{\pagemark}
\rohead{\theEvenPage}
\rofoot{}

% Dictionary entry. Based on: https://de.overleaf.com/latex/examples/dictionary-template/pdztbwjxrpmz
\newcommand{\entry}[3]{%
    \lehead{\pagemark\ {#2}}%
    \lohead{\pagemark\ {#2}}%
    \rehead{\theEvenPage\ {#2}}%
    \rohead{\theEvenPage\ {#2}}%
    \textbf{#1}\ {#3}}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-2]

\clearpage

\begin{multicols}{2}
    \entry{Panama}{PAN}{\lipsum[1]}

    \entry{Paternoster}{PAT}{\lipsum[2]}

    \entry{Performance}{PER}{\lipsum[3]}

    \entry{Peter}{PET}{\lipsum[4]}

    \entry{Petersberg}{PET}{\lipsum[5]}

    \entry{Pfanne}{PFA}{\lipsum[6]}

    \entry{Pfirsich}{PFI}{\lipsum[7]}

    \entry{Pflaume}{PFL}{\lipsum[8]}

    \entry{Pisa}{PIS}{\lipsum[9]}

    \entry{Planung}{PLA}{\lipsum[1]}

    \entry{Po}{PO}{\lipsum[2]}

    \entry{Polen}{POL}{\lipsum[3]}

    \entry{Portugal}{POR}{\lipsum[4]}

    \entry{Primel}{PRI}{\lipsum[5]}

    \entry{Punkt}{PUN}{\lipsum[6]}
\end{multicols}
\end{document}

The guide-words are showing the first entry from the next page and not the once I need.
Does anybody has an idea how this can be resolved?


Because of the asynchronous output, you should always use the mark-mechanism to put content depending text in the page header or footer:
\documentclass[%
    12pt,
    parskip=false,
]{scrbook}

\usepackage[manualmark]{scrlayer-scrpage}

\usepackage[german]{babel} % Old rules

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[babel=true]{microtype}
\setmainfont[Numbers={Proportional,OldStyle},Ligatures={Common,Rare,Historic}]{Libertinus Serif}
\setsansfont[Numbers={Proportional,OldStyle}]{GilliusADF}
\fontspec{inconsolata}

\usepackage{ragged2e}

\usepackage{multicol}

\usepackage{lipsum}

% Double page numbering based on: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18156/figures-on-left-pages-text-on-right-ones-with-class-book-numbering-only-on-rig
\renewcommand\thepage{\number\numexpr ((2*\the\value{page})-1)\relax} % Die Seitennummer wird immer um 2 erhöht
\newcommand{\theEvenPage}{\number\numexpr (\thepage+1)\relax} % Die gerade Seitenzahl rechts
\newcommand*{\EvenPageMark}{{\usekomafont{pagenumber}{\theEvenPage}}}% analogous to the definition of \pagemark

\clearpairofpagestyles
\lehead{\pagemark\ \rightmark}
\rehead{\leftmark\ \EvenPageMark}
\lohead{\pagemark\ \rightmark}
\rohead{\leftmark\ \EvenPageMark}


% Dictionary entry. Based on: https://de.overleaf.com/latex/examples/dictionary-template/pdztbwjxrpmz
\newcommand{\entry}[3]{%
  \par% added, because each entry should start a new paragraph
  \markdouble{#2}% added for the mark → KOMA-Script manual
  \textbf{#1}\ {#3}}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-2]

\clearpage

\begin{multicols}{2}
    \entry{Panama}{PAN}{\lipsum[1]}

    \entry{Paternoster}{PAT}{\lipsum[2]}

    \entry{Performance}{PER}{\lipsum[3]}

    \entry{Peter}{PET}{\lipsum[4]}

    \entry{Petersberg}{PET}{\lipsum[5]}

    \entry{Pfanne}{PFA}{\lipsum[6]}

    \entry{Pfirsich}{PFI}{\lipsum[7]}

    \entry{Pflaume}{PFL}{\lipsum[8]}

    \entry{Pisa}{PIS}{\lipsum[9]}

    \entry{Planung}{PLA}{\lipsum[1]}

    \entry{Po}{PO}{\lipsum[2]}

    \entry{Polen}{POL}{\lipsum[3]}

    \entry{Portugal}{POR}{\lipsum[4]}

    \entry{Primel}{PRI}{\lipsum[5]}

    \entry{Punkt}{PUN}{\lipsum[6]}
\end{multicols}
\end{document}


See the KOMA-Script manual for more information on using \leftmark, \rightmark, \markdouble etc.
BTW: There would even be an alternative using \automark and a standard sectioning command:
\documentclass[%
    12pt,
    parskip=false,
    headings=optiontohead,
]{scrbook}

\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}

\usepackage[german]{babel} % Old rules

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[babel=true]{microtype}
\setmainfont[Numbers={Proportional,OldStyle},Ligatures={Common,Rare,Historic}]{Libertinus Serif}
\setsansfont[Numbers={Proportional,OldStyle}]{GilliusADF}
\fontspec{inconsolata}

\usepackage{ragged2e}

\usepackage{multicol}

\usepackage{lipsum}

% Double page numbering based on: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18156/figures-on-left-pages-text-on-right-ones-with-class-book-numbering-only-on-rig
\renewcommand\thepage{\number\numexpr ((2*\the\value{page})-1)\relax} % Die Seitennummer wird immer um 2 erhöht
\newcommand{\theEvenPage}{\number\numexpr (\thepage+1)\relax} % Die gerade Seitenzahl rechts
\newcommand*{\EvenPageMark}{{\usekomafont{pagenumber}{\theEvenPage}}}% analogous to the definition of \pagemark

\clearpairofpagestyles
\automark[subparagraph]{subparagraph}
\lehead{\pagemark\ \rightmark}
\rehead{\leftmark\ \EvenPageMark}
\lohead{\pagemark\ \rightmark}
\rohead{\leftmark\ \EvenPageMark}


% Dictionary entry. Based on: https://de.overleaf.com/latex/examples/dictionary-template/pdztbwjxrpmz
\newcommand{\entry}[3]{%
  \subparagraph[{#2}]{#1}#3%
}
\RedeclareSectionCommand[beforeskip=0pt]{subparagraph}
\setkomafont{subparagraph}{\rmfamily}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-2]

\clearpage

\begin{multicols}{2}
    \entry{Panama}{PAN}{\lipsum[1]}

    \entry{Paternoster}{PAT}{\lipsum[2]}

    \entry{Performance}{PER}{\lipsum[3]}

    \entry{Peter}{PET}{\lipsum[4]}

    \entry{Petersberg}{PET}{\lipsum[5]}

    \entry{Pfanne}{PFA}{\lipsum[6]}

    \entry{Pfirsich}{PFI}{\lipsum[7]}

    \entry{Pflaume}{PFL}{\lipsum[8]}

    \entry{Pisa}{PIS}{\lipsum[9]}

    \entry{Planung}{PLA}{\lipsum[1]}

    \entry{Po}{PO}{\lipsum[2]}

    \entry{Polen}{POL}{\lipsum[3]}

    \entry{Portugal}{POR}{\lipsum[4]}

    \entry{Primel}{PRI}{\lipsum[5]}

    \entry{Punkt}{PUN}{\lipsum[6]}
\end{multicols}
\end{document}


Wow, this is a great answer and solution. Thank you very much
