\nopagebreak has no effect in \newcommand environment
I have a follow up question to my last question (How to create the guide-words in a dictionary)
I'm working on a dictionary from the 18th century which contains translations for each entry in eight languages. To make life easier I created a \newcommand for this.
\newcommand{\entrygeneric}[2]{%
    \begin{itemize}[labelindent=1.2em,labelwidth=2.4em,align=parleft,leftmargin=!]
        \item[\textit{#1}]{#2}
    \end{itemize}}

\newcommand{\entrynl}[1]{\entrygeneric{Holl.} {\begin{dutch} #1 \end{dutch}}} 
\newcommand{\entryda}[1]{\entrygeneric{Dän.} {\begin{dan} #1 \end{dan}}}
\newcommand{\entrysv}[1]{\entrygeneric{Schw.} {\begin{swed} #1 \end{swed}}}
\newcommand{\entryen}[1]{\entrygeneric{Engl.} {\begin{brit} #1 \end{brit}}}
\newcommand{\entryfr}[1]{\entrygeneric{Franz.} {\begin{fren} #1 \end{fren}}}
\newcommand{\entryit}[1]{\entrygeneric{Ital.} {\begin{ital} #1 \end{ital}}}
\newcommand{\entryes}[1]{\entrygeneric{Span.} {\begin{espan} #1 \end{espan}}}
\newcommand{\entrypt}[1]{\entrygeneric{Port.} {\begin{port} #1 \end{port}}}

The issue I'm facing is that I can't avoid column or page breaks after the headline and this seems to be related to my /newcommand environment. It works fine if I enter just plain text.
How can I modify my \newcommand to avoid page breaks after the headline?
Working example:
\documentclass[%
    12pt,
    parskip=false,
]{scrbook}

\usepackage[manualmark]{scrlayer-scrpage}

\usepackage[main=german,dutch,danish,swedish,british,french,italian,spanish,portuguese]{babel} % Verwednung der alten Rechtschreibung
\babeltags{german=german}
\babeltags{dutch=dutch}
\babeltags{dan=danish}
\babeltags{swed=swedish}
\babeltags{brit=british}
\babeltags{fren=french}
\babeltags{ital=italian}
\babeltags{espan=spanish}
\babeltags{port=portuguese}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\defaultfontfeatures{Renderer=OpenType}
\usepackage{luaotfload} 
\usepackage[babel=true]{microtype}

\usepackage{multicol}
\setlength{\parindent}{1.2em}

% Page numbering, see: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/719862/how-to-create-the-guide-words-in-a-dictionary
\renewcommand\thepage{\number\numexpr ((2*\the\value{page})-1)\relax} % Die Seitennummer wird immer um 2 erhöht
\newcommand{\theEvenPage}{\number\numexpr (\thepage+1)\relax} % Die gerade Seitenzahl rechts
\newcommand*{\EvenPageMark}{{\usekomafont{pagenumber}{\theEvenPage}}} % Analog zur definition von \pagemark

\clearpairofpagestyles
\lehead{\pagemark\ \rightmark}
\rehead{\leftmark\ \EvenPageMark}
\lohead{\pagemark\ \rightmark}
\rohead{\leftmark\ \EvenPageMark}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist{%
    noitemsep,%
    partopsep=0pt,topsep=0pt,parsep=0pt,%
    label=\alph*),%
    leftmargin=1.2em,%
}

% Dictionary - herader for entries
\newcommand{\entry}[2]{%
    \markdouble{#2}%
    \vskip 4pt\noindent{\large{#1}\nopagebreak}}

% Dictionary - translations in different languages
\newcommand{\entrygeneric}[2]{%
    \begin{itemize}[labelindent=1.2em,labelwidth=2.4em,align=parleft,leftmargin=!]
        \item[\textit{#1}]{#2}
    \end{itemize}
}%

\newcommand{\entrynl}[1]{\entrygeneric{Holl.} {\begin{dutch} #1 \end{dutch}}} 
\newcommand{\entryda}[1]{\entrygeneric{Dän.} {\begin{dan} #1 \end{dan}}}
\newcommand{\entrysv}[1]{\entrygeneric{Schw.} {\begin{swed} #1 \end{swed}}}
\newcommand{\entryen}[1]{\entrygeneric{Engl.} {\begin{brit} #1 \end{brit}}}
\newcommand{\entryfr}[1]{\entrygeneric{Franz.} {\begin{fren} #1 \end{fren}}}
\newcommand{\entryit}[1]{\entrygeneric{Ital.} {\begin{ital} #1 \end{ital}}}
\newcommand{\entryes}[1]{\entrygeneric{Span.} {\begin{espan} #1 \end{espan}}}
\newcommand{\entrypt}[1]{\entrygeneric{Port.} {\begin{port} #1 \end{port}}}

\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{2}
    % AAK
    \entry{AAK.}{AAK}

    \entrynl{Aak.}

    \entryda{Et Fartöj paa Rhinſtrömmen.}

    \entrysv{Et Fart\r og ſom nyttias p\r a Rhinſtrömen.}

    \entryen{A ſort of flat bottomed lighter employed on the Rhine.}

    \entryfr{Aque, Acque.}

    \entryit{Un battello con fondo piano, di cui ſi ſervono ſopra il Reno.}

    \entryes{Una barca con fondo llano. ſobre el Reno.}

    \entrypt{Eſpecie de barca chata ſobre o Rheno.}

    Der Name eines Fahrzeuges, womit der Rheinwein nach Holland gebracht wird. Es hat einen flachen Boden, iſt unten breit und wird nach oben zu enger; auch iſt es dabey hoch von Bord und hat einen breiten Vor- und Hinterſteven.

    % AAP
    \entry{AAP.}{APP} (\textit{Hochdeutſch} Affe.)

    \entrynl{Aap.}

    \entryda{Aben.}

    \entrysv{Apan.}

    \entryen{The mizen ſtay-ſail.}

    \entryfr{ Voile d'etay d'artimon, Foc de derriere.}

    \entryit{La carbonera, o ſia la vela di ſtraglio di Mezzana.}

    \entryes{Vela del humo, o vela del eſtay de meſana.}

    \entrypt{Rabeca, ou vela do eſtay da mezena.}

    Dieſen Namen führt auch das Beſahnſtagſegel. (Fig. 102. b.)

    % AAPENFALL
    \entry{AAPENFALL.}{AAP}

    \entrynl{Aapenval.}

    \entryda{Abe-Fald.}

    \entrysv{Apan-eller Aben-Fall.}

    \entryen{The haliard of the mizen. ſtay-ſail.}

    \entryfr{La driſſe de la voile d'etay d'artimon.}

    \entryit{La drizza della carbonera.}

    \entryes{La driza de la vela del humo.}

    \entrypt{A driça da rabeca.}    

    So heiſst auch die Beſahnſtagſegel-Fall. ſ. Fall.

    % ABAB
    \entry{ABAB.}{ABA}

    \entrynl{Een turkſch Matroos.}

    \entryda{En tyrkiſk Matros.}

    \entrysv{En tyrkiſk Matros.}

    \entryen{A turkiſh ſailor.}

    \entryfr{Un matelot turc.}

    \entryit{Un marinaro turco.}

    \entryes{Un marinero turco.}

    \entrypt{Hum marinheiro turco.}

    So heiſst bey den Türken ein Matroſe, oder eigentlich ein zum Matroſen angenommener Landmann.

    % ABAKA
    \entry{ABAKA.}{ABA}

    \entrynl{Een gading hennip van de Manillas Eilanden.}

    \entryda{Et ſlags Hamp ſom voxer paa de manilleſke öer.}

    \entrysv{Et ſlags Hampa ſom växer p\r{a} de manillſka öar.}

    \entryen{A kind of hemp brought from the Manillas Islands.}

    \entryfr{Une eſpece de chanvre, qu'on tire des Isles Philippines.}

    \entryit{Una ſpezie di canapa, che ſi trova nelle Manille.}

    \entryes{Una eſpecie de ca\~namo que ſe halla en las Manillas.}

    \entrypt{Huma eſpecie de canhamo que creſce nas Manilhas.}

    Eine Art Flachs oder Hanf, ſo auf einigen der Manilliſchen Infeln wächſt. Er wird aus einer Pflanze gezogen, die daſelbſt Koffo genannt wird, und zu den Bananas oder Paradies-Feigenbäumen gehört. Es giebt davon zwey Sorten, wovon die eine weiſs und die andere grau iſt.
    
    % ABANDONNEMENT
    \entry{ABANDONNEMENT.}{ABA}
    
    \entrynl{Het Abandoneeren van een Schip \&c. aan den Verzekeraar.}

    \entryda{En Aſſtaaelſe og Overladelſe af Gods eller Skib til Aſſuradeuren.}
\end{multicols}
\end{document}

Edit: non-standard fonts removed


You might increase the number of people who can potentially help you by reducing the example to what is actually necessary to reproduce the problem, e.g. removing non-standard fonts will allow more people to test your code.

define your \entry   as proper heading command with \DeclareSectionCommand (KOMA) or \@startsection (kernel), the \@afterheading will be used. And also the mark command will be in the right place, as it is now it can end on the wrong page.

\vskip 4pt\noindent{\large{#1}\nopagebreak} is a rather odd construct. \vskip is a tex primitive so not normally used in latex. then \noindent starts a paragraph, then { starts a group \large then switches font then { starts another group which does nothing then #1 which is OK if it does not start with white space, then } closes a groupthen\nopagebreakis probably added in horizontal mode so delayed then}` close the group . So the text will be broken into lines using large text on a small baseline and then after the last line, a nobreak penalt ywill be added

In my second example in my answer to the linked question, I've already shown how to use sectioning command for the items and therefore avoid page breaks after the heading. However note, some environments explicitly allows page breaks at the beginning. So please also read beginpenalty etc. in the enumitem manual.

Already in the second example to my answer to your first dictionary question I've shown, how to use a sectioning command (\subparagraph) in that example to do what you want. Using a sectioning command also prevents most page breaks immediately after the heading. But note, that some environments explicitly allow page breaks at the beginning. So it could also be useful to read, e.g., the beginpenalty etc. options in the enumitem manual.
Here is one more example defining \entry as sectioning command instead of using an existing one. Note, that this also needs a change of the arguments. Instead of the second argument of \entry in your example an optional first argument is used. Note also the extra option to \documentclass and the \automark command. Both and all settings with \DeclareNewSectionCommand are explained in the KOMA-Script manual.
\documentclass[%
    12pt,
    parskip=false,
    headings=optiontohead,    
]{scrbook}

\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}

\usepackage[main=german,dutch,danish,swedish,british,french,italian,spanish,portuguese]{babel} % Verwednung der alten Rechtschreibung
\babeltags{german=german}
\babeltags{dutch=dutch}
\babeltags{dan=danish}
\babeltags{swed=swedish}
\babeltags{brit=british}
\babeltags{fren=french}
\babeltags{ital=italian}
\babeltags{espan=spanish}
\babeltags{port=portuguese}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\defaultfontfeatures{Renderer=OpenType}
\usepackage{luaotfload} 
\usepackage[babel=true]{microtype}

\usepackage{multicol}
\setlength{\parindent}{1.2em}

% Page numbering, see: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/719862/how-to-create-the-guide-words-in-a-dictionary
\renewcommand\thepage{\number\numexpr ((2*\the\value{page})-1)\relax} % Die Seitennummer wird immer um 2 erhöht
\newcommand{\theEvenPage}{\number\numexpr (\thepage+1)\relax} % Die gerade Seitenzahl rechts
\newcommand*{\EvenPageMark}{{\usekomafont{pagenumber}{\theEvenPage}}} % Analog zur definition von \pagemark

\clearpairofpagestyles
\lehead{\pagemark\ \rightmark}
\rehead{\leftmark\ \EvenPageMark}
\lohead{\pagemark\ \rightmark}
\rohead{\leftmark\ \EvenPageMark}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist{%
    beginpenalty=10000,% no page break at the beginning
    noitemsep,%
    partopsep=0pt,topsep=0pt,parsep=0pt,%
    label=\alph*),%
    leftmargin=1.2em,%
}

\DeclareNewSectionCommand[style=section,level=10,beforeskip=4pt,afterskip=.5em,runin=true,font=\normalfont\large,tocindent=0pt,tocnumwidth=0pt]{entry}
\automark[entry]{entry}

% Dictionary - translations in different languages
\newcommand{\entrygeneric}[3][]{%
    \begin{itemize}[labelindent=1.2em,labelwidth=2.4em,align=parleft,leftmargin=!,#1]
        \item[\textit{#2}]{#3}
    \end{itemize}
}%

\newcommand{\entrynl}[2][]{\entrygeneric{Holl.} {\begin{dutch} #2 \end{dutch}}} 
\newcommand{\entryda}[2][]{\entrygeneric{Dän.} {\begin{dan} #2 \end{dan}}}
\newcommand{\entrysv}[2][]{\entrygeneric{Schw.} {\begin{swed} #2 \end{swed}}}
\newcommand{\entryen}[2][]{\entrygeneric{Engl.} {\begin{brit} #2 \end{brit}}}
\newcommand{\entryfr}[2][]{\entrygeneric{Franz.} {\begin{fren} #2 \end{fren}}}
\newcommand{\entryit}[2][]{\entrygeneric{Ital.} {\begin{ital} #2 \end{ital}}}
\newcommand{\entryes}[2][]{\entrygeneric{Span.} {\begin{espan} #2 \end{espan}}}
\newcommand{\entrypt}[2][]{\entrygeneric{Port.} {\begin{port} #2 \end{port}}}

\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{2}
    % AAK
    \entry[AKK]{AAK.}

    \entrynl[beginpenalty=10000]{Aak.}

    \entryda{Et Fartöj paa Rhinſtrömmen.}

    \entrysv{Et Fart\r og ſom nyttias p\r a Rhinſtrömen.}

    \entryen{A ſort of flat bottomed lighter employed on the Rhine.}

    \entryfr{Aque, Acque.}

    \entryit{Un battello con fondo piano, di cui ſi ſervono ſopra il Reno.}

    \entryes{Una barca con fondo llano. ſobre el Reno.}

    \entrypt{Eſpecie de barca chata ſobre o Rheno.}

    Der Name eines Fahrzeuges, womit der Rheinwein nach Holland gebracht wird. Es hat einen flachen Boden, iſt unten breit und wird nach oben zu enger; auch iſt es dabey hoch von Bord und hat einen breiten Vor- und Hinterſteven.

    % AAP
    \entry[APP]{AAP.} (\textit{Hochdeutſch} Affe.)

    \entrynl[beginpenalty=10000]{Aap.}

    \entryda{Aben.}

    \entrysv{Apan.}

    \entryen{The mizen ſtay-ſail.}

    \entryfr{ Voile d'etay d'artimon, Foc de derriere.}

    \entryit{La carbonera, o ſia la vela di ſtraglio di Mezzana.}

    \entryes{Vela del humo, o vela del eſtay de meſana.}

    \entrypt{Rabeca, ou vela do eſtay da mezena.}

    Dieſen Namen führt auch das Beſahnſtagſegel. (Fig. 102. b.)

    % AAPENFALL
    \entry[APP]{AAPENFALL.}

    \entrynl[beginpenalty=10000]{Aapenval.}

    \entryda{Abe-Fald.}

    \entrysv{Apan-eller Aben-Fall.}

    \entryen{The haliard of the mizen. ſtay-ſail.}

    \entryfr{La driſſe de la voile d'etay d'artimon.}

    \entryit{La drizza della carbonera.}

    \entryes{La driza de la vela del humo.}

    \entrypt{A driça da rabeca.}    

    So heiſst auch die Beſahnſtagſegel-Fall. ſ. Fall.

    % ABAB
    \entry[ABA]{ABAB.}

    \entrynl[beginpenalty=10000]{Een turkſch Matroos.}

    \entryda{En tyrkiſk Matros.}

    \entrysv{En tyrkiſk Matros.}

    \entryen{A turkiſh ſailor.}

    \entryfr{Un matelot turc.}

    \entryit{Un marinaro turco.}

    \entryes{Un marinero turco.}

    \entrypt{Hum marinheiro turco.}

    So heiſst bey den Türken ein Matroſe, oder eigentlich ein zum Matroſen angenommener Landmann.

    % ABAKA
    \entry[ABA]{ABAKA.}

    \entrynl[beginpenalty=10000]{Een gading hennip van de Manillas Eilanden.}

    \entryda{Et ſlags Hamp ſom voxer paa de manilleſke öer.}

    \entrysv{Et ſlags Hampa ſom växer p\r{a} de manillſka öar.}

    \entryen{A kind of hemp brought from the Manillas Islands.}

    \entryfr{Une eſpece de chanvre, qu'on tire des Isles Philippines.}

    \entryit{Una ſpezie di canapa, che ſi trova nelle Manille.}

    \entryes{Una eſpecie de ca\~namo que ſe halla en las Manillas.}

    \entrypt{Huma eſpecie de canhamo que creſce nas Manilhas.}

    Eine Art Flachs oder Hanf, ſo auf einigen der Manilliſchen Infeln wächſt. Er wird aus einer Pflanze gezogen, die daſelbſt Koffo genannt wird, und zu den Bananas oder Paradies-Feigenbäumen gehört. Es giebt davon zwey Sorten, wovon die eine weiſs und die andere grau iſt.
    
    % ABANDONNEMENT
    \entry[ABA]{ABANDONNEMENT.}
    
    \entrynl[beginpenalty=10000]{Het Abandoneeren van een Schip \&c. aan den Verzekeraar.}

    \entryda{En Aſſtaaelſe og Overladelſe af Gods eller Skib til Aſſuradeuren.}
\end{multicols}
\end{document}


In this example even the beginpenalty=10000 would not be needed, because of using an runin section heading.
However, with my notes above and the notes about wrong usage of \large, wrong order of \vskip and \markdouble etc. even your code could be improved:
\documentclass[%
    12pt,
    parskip=false,
]{scrbook}

\usepackage[manualmark]{scrlayer-scrpage}

\usepackage[main=german,dutch,danish,swedish,british,french,italian,spanish,portuguese]{babel} % Verwednung der alten Rechtschreibung
\babeltags{german=german}
\babeltags{dutch=dutch}
\babeltags{dan=danish}
\babeltags{swed=swedish}
\babeltags{brit=british}
\babeltags{fren=french}
\babeltags{ital=italian}
\babeltags{espan=spanish}
\babeltags{port=portuguese}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\defaultfontfeatures{Renderer=OpenType}
\usepackage{luaotfload} 
\usepackage[babel=true]{microtype}

\usepackage{multicol}
\setlength{\parindent}{1.2em}

% Page numbering, see: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/719862/how-to-create-the-guide-words-in-a-dictionary
\renewcommand\thepage{\number\numexpr ((2*\the\value{page})-1)\relax} % Die Seitennummer wird immer um 2 erhöht
\newcommand{\theEvenPage}{\number\numexpr (\thepage+1)\relax} % Die gerade Seitenzahl rechts
\newcommand*{\EvenPageMark}{{\usekomafont{pagenumber}{\theEvenPage}}} % Analog zur definition von \pagemark

\clearpairofpagestyles
\lehead{\pagemark\ \rightmark}
\rehead{\leftmark\ \EvenPageMark}
\lohead{\pagemark\ \rightmark}
\rohead{\leftmark\ \EvenPageMark}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist{%
    noitemsep,%
    partopsep=0pt,topsep=0pt,parsep=0pt,%
    label=\alph*),%
    leftmargin=1.2em,%
}

% Dictionary - herader for entries
\newcommand{\entry}[2]{%
  \vskip 4pt % must be before adding the mark!
  \noindent{\large\markdouble{#2}#1}\nopagebreak
}

% Dictionary - translations in different languages
\newcommand{\entrygeneric}[3][]{%
    \begin{itemize}[labelindent=1.2em,labelwidth=2.4em,align=parleft,leftmargin=!,#1]
        \item[\textit{#2}]{#3}
    \end{itemize}
}%

\newcommand{\entrynl}[2][]{\entrygeneric[#1]{Holl.} {\begin{dutch} #2 \end{dutch}}} 
\newcommand{\entryda}[2][]{\entrygeneric[#1]{Dän.} {\begin{dan} #2 \end{dan}}}
\newcommand{\entrysv}[2][]{\entrygeneric[#1]{Schw.} {\begin{swed} #2 \end{swed}}}
\newcommand{\entryen}[2][]{\entrygeneric[#1]{Engl.} {\begin{brit} #2 \end{brit}}}
\newcommand{\entryfr}[2][]{\entrygeneric[#1]{Franz.} {\begin{fren} #2 \end{fren}}}
\newcommand{\entryit}[2][]{\entrygeneric[#1]{Ital.} {\begin{ital} #2 \end{ital}}}
\newcommand{\entryes}[2][]{\entrygeneric[#1]{Span.} {\begin{espan} #2 \end{espan}}}
\newcommand{\entrypt}[2][]{\entrygeneric[#1]{Port.} {\begin{port} #2 \end{port}}}

\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{2}
    % AAK
    \entry{AAK.}{AAK}

    \entrynl[beginpenalty=10000]{Aak.}

    \entryda{Et Fartöj paa Rhinſtrömmen.}

    \entrysv{Et Fart\r og ſom nyttias p\r a Rhinſtrömen.}

    \entryen{A ſort of flat bottomed lighter employed on the Rhine.}

    \entryfr{Aque, Acque.}

    \entryit{Un battello con fondo piano, di cui ſi ſervono ſopra il Reno.}

    \entryes{Una barca con fondo llano. ſobre el Reno.}

    \entrypt{Eſpecie de barca chata ſobre o Rheno.}

    Der Name eines Fahrzeuges, womit der Rheinwein nach Holland gebracht wird. Es hat einen flachen Boden, iſt unten breit und wird nach oben zu enger; auch iſt es dabey hoch von Bord und hat einen breiten Vor- und Hinterſteven.

    % AAP
    \entry{AAP.}{APP} (\textit{Hochdeutſch} Affe.)

    \entrynl[beginpenalty=10000]{Aap.}

    \entryda{Aben.}

    \entrysv{Apan.}

    \entryen{The mizen ſtay-ſail.}

    \entryfr{ Voile d'etay d'artimon, Foc de derriere.}

    \entryit{La carbonera, o ſia la vela di ſtraglio di Mezzana.}

    \entryes{Vela del humo, o vela del eſtay de meſana.}

    \entrypt{Rabeca, ou vela do eſtay da mezena.}

    Dieſen Namen führt auch das Beſahnſtagſegel. (Fig. 102. b.)

    % AAPENFALL
    \entry{AAPENFALL.}{AAP}

    \entrynl[beginpenalty=10000]{Aapenval.}

    \entryda{Abe-Fald.}

    \entrysv{Apan-eller Aben-Fall.}

    \entryen{The haliard of the mizen. ſtay-ſail.}

    \entryfr{La driſſe de la voile d'etay d'artimon.}

    \entryit{La drizza della carbonera.}

    \entryes{La driza de la vela del humo.}

    \entrypt{A driça da rabeca.}    

    So heiſst auch die Beſahnſtagſegel-Fall. ſ. Fall.

    % ABAB
    \entry{ABAB.}{ABA}

    \entrynl[beginpenalty=10000]{Een turkſch Matroos.}

    \entryda{En tyrkiſk Matros.}

    \entrysv{En tyrkiſk Matros.}

    \entryen{A turkiſh ſailor.}

    \entryfr{Un matelot turc.}

    \entryit{Un marinaro turco.}

    \entryes{Un marinero turco.}

    \entrypt{Hum marinheiro turco.}

    So heiſst bey den Türken ein Matroſe, oder eigentlich ein zum Matroſen angenommener Landmann.

    % ABAKA
    \entry{ABAKA.}{ABA}

    \entrynl[beginpenalty=10000]{Een gading hennip van de Manillas Eilanden.}

    \entryda{Et ſlags Hamp ſom voxer paa de manilleſke öer.}

    \entrysv{Et ſlags Hampa ſom växer p\r{a} de manillſka öar.}

    \entryen{A kind of hemp brought from the Manillas Islands.}

    \entryfr{Une eſpece de chanvre, qu'on tire des Isles Philippines.}

    \entryit{Una ſpezie di canapa, che ſi trova nelle Manille.}

    \entryes{Una eſpecie de ca\~namo que ſe halla en las Manillas.}

    \entrypt{Huma eſpecie de canhamo que creſce nas Manilhas.}

    Eine Art Flachs oder Hanf, ſo auf einigen der Manilliſchen Infeln wächſt. Er wird aus einer Pflanze gezogen, die daſelbſt Koffo genannt wird, und zu den Bananas oder Paradies-Feigenbäumen gehört. Es giebt davon zwey Sorten, wovon die eine weiſs und die andere grau iſt.
    
    % ABANDONNEMENT
    \entry{ABANDONNEMENT.}{ABA}
    
    \entrynl[beginpenalty=10000]{Het Abandoneeren van een Schip \&c. aan den Verzekeraar.}

    \entryda{En Aſſtaaelſe og Overladelſe af Gods eller Skib til Aſſuradeuren.}
\end{multicols}
\end{document}


In this example at least the last [beginpenalty=10000] is needed. But not only because of this, using the sectioning command version is IMHO the better solution.

This works great!
Thank you very much!
There is still a lot I need to learn

is there an option to make the guide-words centered above the two columns? the page numbers are fine at there position, but it would be great to get the guide-words centered. I'm using your great solution with sectioning

@Dieter If you have a new question or follow-up question like “How to center running heads in twocolumn mode relative to the column width?” you should ask a new question. However, I would try a \makebox[\columnwidth][c]{…} inside the \…head commands. See a LaTeX introduction for more information about \makebox.

Yes this works. Thank you very much. And also thanks for the hint with asking a new question.
