Catchwords not working with multicols
Now I'm facing the next hurdle.
I want to have Catchwords in my document as shown here:

It works fine with the package fwlw (First Word Last Word) as long as I do not use multicols.
W/o multicols:

But the catchwords disappear when I'm using a mutlicols environment.
Does anybody has experience using catchwords together with multicols or any hint how to resolve this?
I really appreciate your support.

Here is my MWE which is based on my last question (\nopagebreak has no effect in \newcommand environment):
\documentclass[%
    paper=A5,
    12pt,
    headings=optiontohead,
]{scrbook}

\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{multicol}

% Page numbering, see: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/719862/how-to-create-the-guide-words-in-a-dictionary
\renewcommand\thepage{\number\numexpr ((2*\the\value{page})-1)\relax} % Die Seitennummer wird immer um 2 erhöht
\newcommand{\theEvenPage}{\number\numexpr (\thepage+1)\relax} % Die gerade Seitenzahl rechts
\newcommand*{\EvenPageMark}{{\usekomafont{pagenumber}{\theEvenPage}}} % Analog zur definition von \pagemark

\usepackage{fwlw} % Package First Word Last Word

\clearpairofpagestyles
\lehead{\pagemark\ \rightmark}
\rehead{\leftmark\ \EvenPageMark}
\lohead{\pagemark\ \rightmark}
\rohead{\leftmark\ \EvenPageMark}

\rofoot{\usebox\NextWordBox}
\refoot{\usebox\NextWordBox}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist{%
    beginpenalty=10000,% no page break at the beginning
    partopsep=0pt,topsep=0pt,parsep=0pt,%
}

\DeclareNewSectionCommand[style=section,level=10,beforeskip=4pt,afterskip=.5em,runin=true,font=\normalfont\large,tocindent=0pt,tocnumwidth=0pt]{entry}
\automark[entry]{entry}

% Dictionary - translations in different languages
\newcommand{\entrygeneric}[3][]{%
    \begin{itemize}[labelindent=1.2em,labelwidth=2.4em,align=parleft,leftmargin=!,#1]
        \item[\textit{#2}]{#3}
    \end{itemize}
}%

\newcommand{\entrynl}[2][]{\entrygeneric{Holl.} {#2}} 
\newcommand{\entryda}[2][]{\entrygeneric{Dän.} {#2}}
\newcommand{\entrysv}[2][]{\entrygeneric{Schw.} {#2}}
\newcommand{\entryen}[2][]{\entrygeneric{Engl.} {#2}}
\newcommand{\entryfr}[2][]{\entrygeneric{Franz.} {#2}}
\newcommand{\entryit}[2][]{\entrygeneric{Ital.} {#2}}
\newcommand{\entryes}[2][]{\entrygeneric{Span.} {#2}}
\newcommand{\entrypt}[2][]{\entrygeneric{Port.} {#2}}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{2}
    % AAK
    \entry[AKK]{AAK.}

    \entrynl[beginpenalty=10000]{Aak.}

    \entryda{Et Fartöj paa Rhinſtrömmen.}

    \entrysv{Et Fart\r og ſom nyttias p\r a Rhinſtrömen.}

    \entryen{A ſort of flat bottomed lighter employed on the Rhine.}

    \entryfr{Aque, Acque.}

    \entryit{Un battello con fondo piano, di cui ſi ſervono ſopra il Reno.}

    \entryes{Una barca con fondo llano. ſobre el Reno.}

    \entrypt{Eſpecie de barca chata ſobre o Rheno.}

    Der Name eines Fahrzeuges, womit der Rheinwein nach Holland gebracht wird. Es hat einen flachen Boden, iſt unten breit und wird nach oben zu enger; auch iſt es dabey hoch von Bord und hat einen breiten Vor- und Hinterſteven.

    % AAP
    \entry[APP]{AAP.} (\textit{Hochdeutſch} Affe.)

    \entrynl[beginpenalty=10000]{Aap.}

    \entryda{Aben.}

    \entrysv{Apan.}

    \entryen{The mizen ſtay-ſail.}

    \entryfr{ Voile d'etay d'artimon, Foc de derriere.}

    \entryit{La carbonera, o ſia la vela di ſtraglio di Mezzana.}

    \entryes{Vela del humo, o vela del eſtay de meſana.}

    \entrypt{Rabeca, ou vela do eſtay da mezena.}

    Dieſen Namen führt auch das Beſahnſtagſegel. (Fig. 102. b.)

    \lipsum
\end{multicols}
\end{document}

EDIT:
Thanks Ulrike for this hint. I guess you are right and this will not wort with this combination.
But here is a shorter MWE to show this issue:
\documentclass[a5paper]{book}

\usepackage{multicol}

\usepackage{fwlw} % Package First Word Last Word
\pagestyle{NextWordFoot}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{2}
    \lipsum
\end{multicols}
\end{document}


I don't think that it will work without explicit support from multicol, as multicol has its own output routine and so effectively hides the text so that fwlw no longer can find it. Generally: you could make your example much shorter, as most of your code is not related to this problem, you could demonstrate that with a simple lipsum.

I've minimized your MWE and changed the tags, because neither [tag:koma-script] nor fontspec is needed to show the problem.

Besides using the package multicol, it would work with the command \twocolumn. But the layout is just ugly, even with microtype. So this is not an option
