Automatic creations of labels for dictionary entries
I'm working on a dictionary and I'm using this solution provided by @cabohah in this post: \nopagebreak has no effect in \newcommand environment
What I need is to add a label to each entry of my dictionary, because there are many cross-references. This works fine by manually adding labels due to the \DeclareNewSectionCommand.
My question: Is there a possibility to automatically add a label to each new entry?

dict:AAK. for the first
dict:AAP. for the second
dict:AAPENFALL.
dict:ABAB.

Doing it by hand will lead to failures/typos.
I appreciate your support.
Here is the code @cabohah uploaded to my last question:
\documentclass[%
    12pt,
    parskip=false,
    headings=optiontohead,    
]{scrbook}

\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}

\usepackage[main=german,dutch,danish,swedish,british,french,italian,spanish,portuguese]{babel} % Verwednung der alten Rechtschreibung
\babeltags{german=german}
\babeltags{dutch=dutch}
\babeltags{dan=danish}
\babeltags{swed=swedish}
\babeltags{brit=british}
\babeltags{fren=french}
\babeltags{ital=italian}
\babeltags{espan=spanish}
\babeltags{port=portuguese}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\defaultfontfeatures{Renderer=OpenType}
\usepackage{luaotfload} 
\usepackage[babel=true]{microtype}

\usepackage{multicol}
\setlength{\parindent}{1.2em}

% Page numbering, see: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/719862/how-to-create-the-guide-words-in-a-dictionary
\renewcommand\thepage{\number\numexpr ((2*\the\value{page})-1)\relax} % Die Seitennummer wird immer um 2 erhöht
\newcommand{\theEvenPage}{\number\numexpr (\thepage+1)\relax} % Die gerade Seitenzahl rechts
\newcommand*{\EvenPageMark}{{\usekomafont{pagenumber}{\theEvenPage}}} % Analog zur definition von \pagemark

\clearpairofpagestyles
\lehead{\pagemark\ \rightmark}
\rehead{\leftmark\ \EvenPageMark}
\lohead{\pagemark\ \rightmark}
\rohead{\leftmark\ \EvenPageMark}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist{%
    beginpenalty=10000,% no page break at the beginning
    noitemsep,%
    partopsep=0pt,topsep=0pt,parsep=0pt,%
    label=\alph*),%
    leftmargin=1.2em,%
}

\DeclareNewSectionCommand[style=section,level=10,beforeskip=4pt,afterskip=.5em,runin=true,font=\normalfont\large,tocindent=0pt,tocnumwidth=0pt]{entry}
\automark[entry]{entry}

% Dictionary - translations in different languages
\newcommand{\entrygeneric}[3][]{%
    \begin{itemize}[labelindent=1.2em,labelwidth=2.4em,align=parleft,leftmargin=!,#1]
        \item[\textit{#2}]{#3}
    \end{itemize}
}%

\newcommand{\entrynl}[2][]{\entrygeneric{Holl.} {\begin{dutch} #2 \end{dutch}}} 
\newcommand{\entryda}[2][]{\entrygeneric{Dän.} {\begin{dan} #2 \end{dan}}}
\newcommand{\entrysv}[2][]{\entrygeneric{Schw.} {\begin{swed} #2 \end{swed}}}
\newcommand{\entryen}[2][]{\entrygeneric{Engl.} {\begin{brit} #2 \end{brit}}}
\newcommand{\entryfr}[2][]{\entrygeneric{Franz.} {\begin{fren} #2 \end{fren}}}
\newcommand{\entryit}[2][]{\entrygeneric{Ital.} {\begin{ital} #2 \end{ital}}}
\newcommand{\entryes}[2][]{\entrygeneric{Span.} {\begin{espan} #2 \end{espan}}}
\newcommand{\entrypt}[2][]{\entrygeneric{Port.} {\begin{port} #2 \end{port}}}

\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{2}
    % AAK
    \entry[AKK]{AAK.}

    \entrynl[beginpenalty=10000]{Aak.}

    \entryda{Et Fartöj paa Rhinſtrömmen.}

    \entrysv{Et Fart\r og ſom nyttias p\r a Rhinſtrömen.}

    \entryen{A ſort of flat bottomed lighter employed on the Rhine.}

    \entryfr{Aque, Acque.}

    \entryit{Un battello con fondo piano, di cui ſi ſervono ſopra il Reno.}

    \entryes{Una barca con fondo llano. ſobre el Reno.}

    \entrypt{Eſpecie de barca chata ſobre o Rheno.}

    Der Name eines Fahrzeuges, womit der Rheinwein nach Holland gebracht wird. Es hat einen flachen Boden, iſt unten breit und wird nach oben zu enger; auch iſt es dabey hoch von Bord und hat einen breiten Vor- und Hinterſteven.

    % AAP
    \entry[APP]{AAP.} (\textit{Hochdeutſch} Affe.)

    \entrynl[beginpenalty=10000]{Aap.}

    \entryda{Aben.}

    \entrysv{Apan.}

    \entryen{The mizen ſtay-ſail.}

    \entryfr{ Voile d'etay d'artimon, Foc de derriere.}

    \entryit{La carbonera, o ſia la vela di ſtraglio di Mezzana.}

    \entryes{Vela del humo, o vela del eſtay de meſana.}

    \entrypt{Rabeca, ou vela do eſtay da mezena.}

    Dieſen Namen führt auch das Beſahnſtagſegel. (Fig. 102. b.)

    % AAPENFALL
    \entry[APP]{AAPENFALL.}

    \entrynl[beginpenalty=10000]{Aapenval.}

    \entryda{Abe-Fald.}

    \entrysv{Apan-eller Aben-Fall.}

    \entryen{The haliard of the mizen. ſtay-ſail.}

    \entryfr{La driſſe de la voile d'etay d'artimon.}

    \entryit{La drizza della carbonera.}

    \entryes{La driza de la vela del humo.}

    \entrypt{A driça da rabeca.}    

    So heiſst auch die Beſahnſtagſegel-Fall. ſ. Fall.

    % ABAB
    \entry[ABA]{ABAB.}

    \entrynl[beginpenalty=10000]{Een turkſch Matroos.}

    \entryda{En tyrkiſk Matros.}

    \entrysv{En tyrkiſk Matros.}

    \entryen{A turkiſh ſailor.}

    \entryfr{Un matelot turc.}

    \entryit{Un marinaro turco.}

    \entryes{Un marinero turco.}

    \entrypt{Hum marinheiro turco.}

    So heiſst bey den Türken ein Matroſe, oder eigentlich ein zum Matroſen angenommener Landmann.

    % ABAKA
    \entry[ABA]{ABAKA.}

    \entrynl[beginpenalty=10000]{Een gading hennip van de Manillas Eilanden.}

    \entryda{Et ſlags Hamp ſom voxer paa de manilleſke öer.}

    \entrysv{Et ſlags Hampa ſom växer p\r{a} de manillſka öar.}

    \entryen{A kind of hemp brought from the Manillas Islands.}

    \entryfr{Une eſpece de chanvre, qu'on tire des Isles Philippines.}

    \entryit{Una ſpezie di canapa, che ſi trova nelle Manille.}

    \entryes{Una eſpecie de ca\~namo que ſe halla en las Manillas.}

    \entrypt{Huma eſpecie de canhamo que creſce nas Manilhas.}

    Eine Art Flachs oder Hanf, ſo auf einigen der Manilliſchen Infeln wächſt. Er wird aus einer Pflanze gezogen, die daſelbſt Koffo genannt wird, und zu den Bananas oder Paradies-Feigenbäumen gehört. Es giebt davon zwey Sorten, wovon die eine weiſs und die andere grau iſt.
    
    % ABANDONNEMENT
    \entry[ABA]{ABANDONNEMENT.}
    
    \entrynl[beginpenalty=10000]{Het Abandoneeren van een Schip \&c. aan den Verzekeraar.}

    \entryda{En Aſſtaaelſe og Overladelſe af Gods eller Skib til Aſſuradeuren.}
\end{multicols}
\end{document}

