Wrong page referene for enumerate
I'm facing an issue with referencing an enumerate.
I'm having an unusual layout where the page number is increased by 2 per page. On the left side is the odd number, on the right side the even number. And I'm using a two column layout. This is because my document is based on a book from the 18th century.
Please see this picture for my problem. I added some arrows where the \label{...} commands are in the text.

Adding \label{...} directly after \item references the previous page if an item starts on a new page (see label 1)
Adding \label{...} at the end of an item references the next page if an item
spans over a page break (see label 5)
Adding \label{...} after the first word of each item works, but does not looks good in my tex-file (see label 2)
And finally the tricky part: label 4 should reference to page 4! So I need to get the odd page number for the left column and the even page number for the right column.

Is there a possibility to achieve this? Mainly for my last question (bullet point 4). The first three bullet points are more "nice to have".
Note: Bullet point 1 - 3 is not related to the two column environment, it also happens in a single column document.

Here my MWE:
\documentclass[12pt]{scrbook}
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[babel=true]{microtype}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{lipsum}

% Page numbering, see: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/719862/how-to-create-the-guide-words-in-a-dictionary
\renewcommand\thepage{\number\numexpr ((2*\the\value{page})-1)\relax} % Increase page number by 2
\newcommand{\theEvenPage}{\number\numexpr (\thepage+1)\relax} % The even page number is in the right
\newcommand*{\EvenPageMark}{{\usekomafont{pagenumber}{\theEvenPage}}}

\clearpairofpagestyles
\lehead{\pagemark}
\rehead{\EvenPageMark}
\lohead{\pagemark}
\rohead{\EvenPageMark}

\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{2}
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item This is the 1st item with some random text to fill the page \lipsum[1]

        \item This is the 2nd item with some random text to fill the page \lipsum[2]

        \item This is the 3rd item with some random text to fill the page \lipsum[3]

        \item This is the 4th item with some random text to fill the page \lipsum[4][1-7]

        \item This is the 5th item with some random text to fill the page \lipsum[5][1-8]

        \item \label{itm:1} This  \label{itm:2} is the 6th item with some random text to fill the page \lipsum[6] \label{itm:3}

        \item This is the 7th item with some random text to fill the page \lipsum[7-9]

        \item \label{itm:4} This is the 8th item with some random text to fill the page \lipsum[10] \label{itm:5}
    \end{enumerate}
\end{multicols}

Label 1 is referenced on page \pageref{itm:1}, but I would expect page 3

Label 2 is referenced on page \pageref{itm:2} as expected

Label 3 is referenced on page \pageref{itm:3} as expected

Label 4 is referenced on page \pageref{itm:4}, but I would expect page 4

Label 5 is referenced on page \pageref{itm:5}, but I would expect page 4
\end{document}

EDIT:
I had something like this in mind:
\newcommand\mylabel[1]{%
    \docolaction
        {\label{#1}} % Left column
        { } % Center Column
        {\addtocounter{page}{1} \label{#1} \addtocounter{page}{-1}} % Right Column
    \ignorespaces
}

But I have two issues:

The page number is increased by this, but the label is still referencing the the page before increasing the page number. I added \thepage in the following MWE to show this behavior (label 4, 5 and 8)
This command also triggers the \renewcommand\thepage{\number\numexpr ((2*\the\value{page})-1)\relax} command which increases the page number by 2 each time.

MWE:
\documentclass[12pt]{scrbook}
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[babel=true]{microtype}
\usepackage[colaction]{multicol}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{lipsum}

% Page numbering, see: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/719862/how-to-create-the-guide-words-in-a-dictionary
\renewcommand\thepage{\number\numexpr ((2*\the\value{page})-1)\relax} % Increase page number by 2
\newcommand{\theEvenPage}{\number\numexpr (\thepage+1)\relax} % The even page number is in the right
\newcommand*{\EvenPageMark}{{\usekomafont{pagenumber}{\theEvenPage}}}

\newcommand\mylabel[1]{%
    \docolaction
        {\label{#1}} % Left column
        { } % Center Column
        {\addtocounter{page}{1} \thepage{} \label{#1} \addtocounter{page}{-1}} % Right Column
    \ignorespaces
}

\clearpairofpagestyles
\lehead{\pagemark}
\rehead{\EvenPageMark}
\lohead{\pagemark}
\rohead{\EvenPageMark}

\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{2}
%   \colaction
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item \mylabel{itm:1} \lipsum[1]
        \item \mylabel{itm:2} \lipsum[2]
        \item \mylabel{itm:3} \lipsum[3]
        \item \mylabel{itm:4} \lipsum[4]
        \item \mylabel{itm:5} \lipsum[5]
        \item \mylabel{itm:6} \lipsum[6]
        \item \mylabel{itm:7} \lipsum[7]
        \item \mylabel{itm:8} \lipsum[8]
    \end{enumerate}
\end{multicols}

Label 1 is referenced on page  \pageref{itm:1}

Label 2 is referenced on page  \pageref{itm:2}

Label 3 is referenced on page  \pageref{itm:3}

Label 4 is referenced on page  \pageref{itm:4}

Label 5 is referenced on page  \pageref{itm:5}

Label 6 is referenced on page  \pageref{itm:6}

Label 7 is referenced on page  \pageref{itm:7}

Label 8 is referenced on page  \pageref{itm:8}
\end{document}


Just to make sure: you did compile more than once to update all references?

IMHO the result it expected, because \label always uses \thepage (see the definition in latex.ltx resp. source2e.pdf). It does not automatically use \theEvenPage at the right column. So \theEvenPage and \EvenPageMark do work for the page header, but not for labels. You would either have to redefine \thepage or \label to write another page number after the column break. IMHO this can be tricky using multicols. And this is independent from using enumerate. Same would happen for page references to labels outside enumerate.

There might be an option with \docolaction from the multicol package, but that's beyond my skills

I figured out, that the issue with referencing to the previous page, in case an item is at the top of a new page, can be avoided by wrapping the \label{...} in \item\makebox[0pt]{\label{...}}. Maybe there are smarter solutions, but at least it seems to work.

Nice. Suggestion: present your solution as an answer, so future reader can reuse it more easily.

Note: Because of the asynchronous page breaking expansion of \thepage in the write to the aux file is delayed until shipout.

Is there an option to pass the page number manually to \label as a parameter?

\leavevmode\label  should work. And with a current LaTeX it should be possible to detect in which column you are. But I can't look today.

I found a solution to pass the required page number based on the current column. The current column is accessed by \docolaction from package multicol. And then the page number is passed by using a custom label which was possible by using the package hyperref. Any comment is appreciated if further optimizations or easier solutions are possible.
New MWE:
    \documentclass[12pt]{scrbook}
    \usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
    \usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
    \usepackage{fontspec}
    \usepackage[babel=true]{microtype}
    \usepackage[colaction]{multicol}
    \usepackage{enumitem}
    \usepackage{lipsum}
    
    \usepackage{hyperref}
    
    % Page numbering, see: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/719862/how-to-create-the-guide-words-in-a-dictionary
    \renewcommand\thepage{\number\numexpr((2*\the\value{page})-1)\relax} % Increase page number by 2
    \newcommand{\theEvenPage}{\number\numexpr(\thepage+1)\relax} % The even page number is in the right
    \newcommand*{\EvenPageMark}{{\usekomafont{pagenumber}{\theEvenPage}}}
    
    \newcounter{mypage} 
    
    % Modified from https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18191/defining-custom-labels
    \makeatletter
    \newcommand{\mycustomlabel}[3]{%
        \protected@write \@auxout {}{\string \newlabel {#1}{{#2}{#3}{#2}{#1}{}}}%
        \hypertarget{#1}{#2}%
    }
\makeatother
    
    \newcommand\mylabel[1]{%
        \docolaction%
            {\leavevmode\customlabel{#1}{}{\thepage}} % Left column
            {}                                        % Center column
            {                                         % Right column
                \setcounter{mypage}{\number\numexpr (\thepage+1)\relax}%
                \leavevmode\customlabel{#1}{}{\number\value{mypage}}\relax
            }%
        \ignorespaces
    }
    
    \clearpairofpagestyles
    \lehead{\pagemark}
    \rehead{\EvenPageMark}
    \lohead{\pagemark}
    \rohead{\EvenPageMark}
    
    \begin{document}
    \begin{multicols}{2}
    %   \colaction
        \begin{enumerate}
            \item\mylabel{itm:1}This is the 1st item with some random text to fill the page \lipsum[1]
            \item\mylabel{itm:2}This is the 2nd item with some random text to fill the page \lipsum[2]
            \item\mylabel{itm:3}This is the 3rd item with some random text to fill the page \lipsum[3]
            \item\mylabel{itm:4}This is the 4th item with some random text to fill the page \lipsum[4][1-7]
            \item\mylabel{itm:5}This is the 5th item with some random text to fill the page \lipsum[5][1-8]
            \item\mylabel{itm:6}This is the 6th item with some random text to fill the page \lipsum[6]
            \item\mylabel{itm:7}This is the 7th item with some random text to fill the page \lipsum[7-9]
            \item\mylabel{itm:8}This is the 8th item with some random text to fill the page \lipsum[10]
        \end{enumerate}
    \end{multicols}
    
    Label 1 is referenced on page \pageref{itm:1}
    
    Label 2 is referenced on page \pageref{itm:2}
    
    Label 3 is referenced on page \pageref{itm:3}
    
    Label 4 is referenced on page \pageref{itm:4}
    
    Label 5 is referenced on page \pageref{itm:5}
    
    Label 6 is referenced on page \pageref{itm:6}
    
    Label 7 is referenced on page \pageref{itm:7}
    
    Label 8 is referenced on page \pageref{itm:8}
    \end{document}

Edit:
Update with \hypertarget{#1}{#2} to make the links functional. Also added some % to avoid unintended horizontal space in the pdf output
