cross-referencing with page-information as parameter
Is there an option to pass the page-information as parameter to a \label command? Like \label[page]{name}
Here a not working MWE:
\documentclass{book}

\begin{document}
\section{Section}
\label[5]{sec:sec1}

\pageref{sec:sec1}
\end{document}


Are you familiar with the varioref package and its \vref, \vpageref, \vrefrange, and \vpagerefrange user-level macros?

Can you describe what you want to do with the page information? For example, what does [5] represent in your example and what do you want to do with it? Do you want \pageref{sec:sec1} to return 5 because of the optional parameter?

@Werner: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/722722/. (I assume.) Can I abuse a comment to ask if you ever received a reply to your 2022 email to the fontinst list? (I tried to ping you in chat yesterday but I can't because you've been there recently enough, I guess.) [I also was not really sure I followed your point.]

@Werner: Yes, the 5 is only there as an example. In this case I would expect to get 5 as the return value for \pageref, albeit the label definition is on the first page. Just changing the page number does not work in my case, I need an option to pass manually a page number.

@Mico: Thank you very much for this hint. I had a short look at this package but I do not see an option to pass manually a page number

Sorry but your idea is wrong. You don't know on which page the label will be and you would have to constantly check if the page didn't change (and if it is fix you could simply type 5 instead of the pageref).

@UlrikeFischer: I totally agree. Hard coded page numbers make no sense. But this is only to keep my example as small as possible. My document is a two column layout (multicol) and the page numbering is always the odd page numbers for the left column and the even page number for the right column. Both values are available as variable. My issue is how to make cross-references to the left or right column. \docolaction gives me the current column.
Here my complete MWE: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/722722/wrong-page-referene-for-enumerate?noredirect=1#comment1798625_722722

The values are not available during processing only at shipout due to the asynchronous page breaking. As I commented in the other question I can't look now I'm travelling, perhaps in the evening.
